# Which process/program create/write the file which I/O is redirected to?

Tags: shell, fedora, io-redirection, selinux

When learning SELinux, I executed `semanage fcontext -l > fcontext.txt` under `/root` directory to dump massive fcontext information to a file. The funny result is: `fcontext.txt` was created, but the size of it is 0.

I asked in **#fedora-selinux** IRC channel, a Fedora QA told me try change the type of SELinux context of `fcontext.txt` to `semanage_tmp_t`. It works finally.

But what still confusing me is:

Which process/program create/write the standard output to the redirected file ? (so that SELinux targetd policy should applied to that process/program)

- The bash shell ? `/bin/bash`
- or semanage (it's a python script) ? `/usr/sbin/semanage`
- or the interpreter - python ? `/usr/bin/python`

I thought it should be the bash shell, because I/O redirection is controlled by shell (right?), not the program itself. so semanage/python didn't create the file directly.

Comment: btw, pipe works fine, `semanage fcontext -l | cat > fcontext.txt` will fill the `fcontext.txt` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right: redirection for input and output streams is done by the shell.

In more detail, when you execute a command through the shell the
following procedure is run:

1. The shell [forks](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) to create a new process.
2. The newly-created shell ("child" shell) applies redirections: it
   opens the file specified as output target (resp. input source) and sets
   it as the new STDOUT (resp. STDIN) stream (using the
   [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) system call).
3. The"child" shell execs the command you asked to run, using the
   [execve(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call, which
   replaces the shell process with a new program.

Comment: thanks, this explains why the file was created (step 2), but no contents were written (step 3) if SELinux=Enforcing.