# How to turn off stdout buffering in a pipe?

Tags: shell, pipe, stdout, buffer

I have a script which calls two commands:

```
long_running_command | print_progress
```

The `long_running_command` prints progress but I'm unhappy with it. I'm using `print_progress` to make it nicer (namely, I print the progress in a single line).

**The problem:** Connection a pipe to stdout also activates a 4K buffer, so the nice print program gets nothing ... nothing ... nothing ... *a whole lot* ... :)

How can I disable the `4K` buffer for the `long_running_command` (no, I do not have the source)?

Comment: So when you run long_running_command without piping you can see the progress updates properly, but when piping they get buffered?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: The inability for a simple way of controlling buffering has been a problem for decades.  For example, see: http://marc.info/?l=glibc-bug&m=98313957306297&w=4 which basicly says "I can't be arsed doing this and here's some clap-trap to justify my position"

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/589614/67097

Comment: It is actually stdio not the pipe that causes a delay while waiting for enough data.  Pipes do have a capacity, but as soon as there is any data written to the pipe, it is immediately ready to read at the other end.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

You can use the [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) command (which comes as part of the [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) package), e.g.

```
unbuffer long_running_command | print_progress
```

`unbuffer` connects to `long_running_command` via a pseudoterminal (pty), which makes the system treat it as an interactive process, therefore not using the 4-kiB buffering in the pipeline that is the likely cause of the delay.

For longer pipelines, you may have to unbuffer each command (except the final one), e.g.

```
unbuffer x | unbuffer -p y | z
```

Comment: In fact, the use of a pty to connect to interactive processes is true of expect in general.

Comment: When pipelining calls to unbuffer, you should use the -p argument so that unbuffer reads from stdin.

Comment: Note: On debian systems, this is called `expect_unbuffer` and is in the `expect-dev` package, not the `expect` package

Comment: When I type Ctrl+Z to suspend the program, `unbuffer` doesn't pass the word along, so the program continues to use CPU.  I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @bdonlan: At least on Ubuntu (debian-based), `expect-dev` provides both `unbuffer` and `expect_unbuffer` (the former is a symlink to the latter). The links are available since `expect 5.44.1.14-1` (2009).

Comment: `unbuffer` is in the main `expect` package on debian now (it's still a symlink to `expect_unbuffer`, which is also in the main `expect` package)

Comment: Note: On Ubuntu 14.04.x systems, it's also in the expect-dev package.

Comment: Iʼm getting weird errors with `unbuffer`.  A minimum reproducible example for me is `unbuffer cat /dev/urandom > /dev/null`; this causes a segfault within a couple seconds.  This does not happen with `/dev/zero` or without `unbuffer`, making me think `expect` is trying to do *something* with the output.  Does that seem plausible?

Comment: This is not working for me when trying to unbuffer ffmpeg

Answer (score 574):

Another way to skin this cat is to use the [`stdbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) program, which is part of the GNU Coreutils (FreeBSD also has its own one).

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 command
```

This turns off buffering completely for input, output and error. For some applications, line buffering may be more suitable for performance reasons:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL command
```

<sub>Note that it only works for `stdio` buffering (`printf()`, `fputs()`...) for dynamically linked applications, and only if that application doesn't otherwise adjust the buffering of its standard streams by itself, though that should cover most applications.</sub>

Comment: "unbuffer" needs to be installed in Ubuntu, which is inside the package: *expect-dev* which is 2MB...

Comment: This works great on the default raspbian install to unbuffer logging. I found `sudo stdbuff … command` works although `stdbuff … sudo command` didn't.

Comment: @qdii `stdbuf` does not work with `tee`, because `tee` overwrites the defaults set by `stdbuf`. See the manual page of `stdbuf`.

Comment: @lepe Bizarrely, unbuffer has dependencies on x11 and tcl/tk, meaning it actually needs >80 MB if you're installing it on a server without them.

Comment: Excellent! Wish I could upvote more. I had a background process that was not writing to a log ... even after being terminated, it wouldn't write the buffer out. `stdbuf` worked like a charm!

Comment: @lepe, not that bizarre, since it's part of Expect, thus written in TCL, and TCL and Tk are often packaged together... and Tk has that whole, fun chain.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - indeed TCL/Tk are seemingly inseparable. [`jim`](http://jim.tcl.tk/index.html/doc/www/www/index.html) is usually more preferable where TCL is concerned, from where I sit. It doesn't pack some ginormous dot-net style dependency chain in for a simple scripting language.

Comment: FWIW, I can't get this to work at all.  I'm trying to pipe a long-running command to ts (timestamper), and I can't find *any* variant that works, even with sudo on the inside.  Example:  sudo stdbuf -o0 -e0 -i0 /usr/local/bin/ec2-snapshot-all | stdbuf -o0 -e0 -i0 ts  (and moving the sudo dosen't help).

In contrast, the socat solution works perfectly.

Comment: @rlpowell, setting the value to 0 will make it unbuffered.  You need to set it to a value higher then 0 or if you want, set it to L and it will be line buffered.  Type `stdbuf --help` for all the info you need.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, unbuffered is what I want, but it stays buffered in nice, big multiline chunks.

Comment: @qdii `stdbuf` uses `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism to insert its own dynamically loaded library `libstdbuf.so`. This means that it will not work with these kinds executables: with setuid or file capabilities set, statically linked, not using standard libc. In these cases it is better to use the solutions with `unbuffer` / `script` / `socat`. See also [stdbuf with setuid/capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18624182/320437).

Comment: Does `stdbuf` have hybrid line + block buffering? That is output when a newline is encountered, or when the buffer reaches a high watermark?

Comment: when piping commands do I need to prefix each segment with `stdbuf`?

Comment: This didn't work for me, piping `mycommand | tee /dev/tty | awk 'awkstuff'` -- I tried putting `stdbuf -o0 -e0 -i0` in front of each and all three of these commands. What ended up working was using `awk` (actually `mawk`)  as `awk -Winteractive`.

Comment: @brandones: this is probably because of an internal buffer of `mawk` on which `stdbuf` cannot act. See also https://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html

Comment: @jchook Yes, what was said in the accepted answer using unbuffer above also applies here: "for longer pipelines, you may have to unbuffer each command"

Comment: Is there a way to force the pipe/printf buffers externally for already running process with known PID?

Comment: @Mvorisek: I don't know, I guess this could be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Note that this will not work if the command overrides the buffer settings (e.g. python commands).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654364/why-stdbuf-has-no-effect-on-python

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong How can I verify `stdbuf` whether for a specific command or not,say `adb`.

Comment: @John What do you mean by "verify `stdbuf`"? You can just try to use it. If you want to go the hard way to check it before trying, you can verify if the binary calls the IO stream functions https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-on-Streams.html To do this you can run `ltrace -x '*@libc.so*' your_binary` and analyze the output :)

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Sorry for my poor English. I mean, how can I verify `stdbuf stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0` whether works for a specific command or not, say `adb`.

Comment: @John There is nothing new I can add. Just try to use it and check if it has the effect you expect. If it behaves differently, you can check the library calls using `ltrace` but this needs a knowledge and time.

Answer (score 106):

For `grep`, `sed` and `awk` you can force output to be line buffered. You can use:

```
grep --line-buffered
```

Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line buffered when standard output is a terminal and block buffered other-wise.

```
sed -u
```

Make output line buffered.

See this page for more information:
http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html

Comment: Notably `python` also supports the `-u` parameter to disable buffering.

Comment: Using grep(etc.) like this won't work.  By the time you've executed `long_running_command` it's too late.  It'll be buffered before it even gets to grep.

Comment: This is still buffered.  what if one wants to see the line progress...

Comment: Should this work with `grep --line-buffered pattern *many*many*files* | head`? It looks like `grep` processes all the files before feeding the output lines to `head`

Comment: And here I thought I was a grep power user.

Comment: Ah, fantastic! Here is me watching IOPS on a ZFS resilver: `zpool iostat -vH tank 1 | grep --line-buffered ata-TOSHIBA_HDWG460_NVYXDA0GMFR1H | awk '{print $5;fflush()}' | average` .  Notice the fflush() in awk to get it to also unbuffer.

Answer (score 105):

Yet another way to turn on line-buffering output mode for the `long_running_command` is to use the `script` command that runs your `long_running_command` in a pseudo terminal (pty).

```
script -q /dev/null long_running_command | print_progress      # (FreeBSD, Mac OS X)
script -q -c "long_running_command" /dev/null | print_progress # (Linux)
```

Comment: +1 nice trick, since `script` is such an old command, it should be available on all Unix-like platforms.

Comment: you also need `-q` on Linux: `script -q -c 'long_running_command' /dev/null | print_progress`

Comment: It seems like script reads from `stdin`, which makes it impossible to run such a `long_running_command` in the background, at least when started from interactive terminal. To workaround, I was able to redirect stdin from `/dev/null`, since my `long_running_command` doesn't use `stdin`.

Comment: Even works on Android.

Comment: I can confirm that this also works on Mac

Comment: One significant disadvantage: ctrl-z no longer works (i.e. I can't suspend the script).  This can be fixed by, for example: echo | sudo script -c /usr/local/bin/ec2-snapshot-all /dev/null | ts
 , if you don't mind not being able to interact with the program.

Comment: None of the other commands exist in Busybox, this one does, but when I tried it, it didn't work. Could just be my situation though, I was doing something weird with file descriptors.

Comment: Great.  This works to make the control characters work with `script -q -c 'python -c "import pdb, sys; pdb.set_trace()"' /dev/null | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with the `script` command in SmartOS/Solaris derivatives

Comment: A disadvantage that I found was that `script` will mask the command return status with its own (usually 0). If the `print_progress` or the rest of the compound command depends on it (by using `||` or `&&` constructs), it'll not work as expected.

Comment: Be very careful if the script itself is in the middle of a pipe, I did `cat a | script python b.py | sink` and it overwrote b.py. Had I not had the file open in vim I'd be out an hour of work.

Comment: Using `script` worked for me where `stdbuf` did not. Use `script -e -c <cmd> /dev/null` if you want `script` to return the exit code of `<cmd>`.

Answer (score 59):

If it is a problem with the libc modifying its buffering / flushing when output does not go to a terminal, you should try [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). You can create a bidirectional stream between almost any kind of I/O mechanism. One of those is a forked program speaking to a pseudo tty.

```
 socat EXEC:long_running_command,pty,ctty STDIO
```

What it does is

- create a pseudo tty
- fork long_running_command with the slave side of the pty as stdin/stdout
- establish a bidirectional stream between the master side of the pty and the second address (here it is STDIO)

If this gives you the same output as `long_running_command`, then you can continue with a pipe.

Edit : Wow
Did  not see the unbuffer answer ! Well, socat is a great tool anyway, so I might just leave this answer

Comment: ...and I didn't know about socat - looks kinda like netcat only perhaps more so. ;)  Thanks and +1.

Comment: I'd use `socat -u exec:long_running_command,pty,end-close -` here

Answer (score 25):

You can use

```
long_running_command 1>&2 |& print_progress
```

The problem is that libc will line-buffer when stdout to screen and block-buffer when stdout to a file, but no-buffer for stderr.

I don't think it's the problem with pipe buffer, it's all about libc's buffer policy.

Comment: You're right; my question is still: How can I influence libc's buffer policy without recompiling?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fd1 will redirected to stderr

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas i dont get your arguing point. plz do a test, it works

Comment: OK, what's happening is that with both `zsh` (where `|&` comes from adapted from csh) and `bash`, when you do `cmd1 >&2 |& cmd2`, both fd 1 and 2 are connected to the outer stdout. So it works at preventing buffering when that outer stdout is a terminal, but only because the output doesn't go through the pipe (so `print_progress` prints nothing). So it's the same as `long_running_command & print_progress` (except that print_progress stdin is a pipe that has no writer). You can verify with `ls -l /proc/self/fd >&2 |& cat` compared to `ls -l /proc/self/fd |& cat`.

Comment: That's because `|&` is short for `2>&1 |`, literally. So `cmd1 |& cmd2` is `cmd1 1>&2 2>&1 | cmd2`. So, both fd 1 and 2 end up connected to the original stderr, and nothing is left writing to the pipe. (`s/outer stdout/outer stderr/g` in my previous comment).

Comment: This does not solve the original problem but helps when using `tee` as the `print_progress` function. With this solution you get console output immediately but `tee` output remains buffered.

Answer (score 11):

It used to be the case, and probably still is the case, that when standard output is written to a terminal, it is line buffered by default - when a newline is written, the line is written to the terminal.  When standard output is sent to a pipe, it is fully buffered - so the data is only sent to the next process in the pipeline when the standard I/O buffer is filled.

That's the source of the trouble.  I'm not sure whether there is much you can do to fix it without modifying the program writing into the pipe.  You could use the `setvbuf()` function with the `_IOLBF` flag to unconditionally put `stdout` into line buffered mode.  But I don't see an easy way to enforce that on a program.  Or the program can do `fflush()` at appropriate points (after each line of output), but the same comment applies.

I suppose that if you replaced the pipe with a pseudo-terminal, then the standard I/O library would think the output was a terminal (because it is a type of terminal) and would line buffer automatically.  That is a complex way of dealing with things, though.

Comment: Actually, it's an easy way of dealing with things when, as the question says, altering the program code is not an option.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215071/5132

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question and already had lot of answers, but if you wish to avoid the buffer problem, just try something like:

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f /var/log/messages | tee -a /home/your_user_here/logs.txt
```

This will output in real time the logs and also save them into the `logs.txt` file and the buffer will no longer affect the `tail -f` command.

Comment: This looks like the second answer :-/

Comment: stdbuf is included in gnu coreutils(I verified on latest version 8.25).

verified this works on an embedded linux.

Comment: From stdbuf's documentation,  `NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard  streams  ('tee'
       does  for  example)  then  that  will override corresponding changes by
       'stdbuf'.`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the problem is with the pipe. It sounds like your long running process is not flushing its own buffer frequently enough. Changing the pipe's buffer size would be a hack to get round it, but I don't think its possible without rebuilding the kernel - something you wouldn't want to do as a hack, as it probably aversley affect a lot of other processes.

Comment: The root cause is that libc switches to 4k buffering if the stdout is not a tty.

Comment: That is very interesting ! because pipe don't cause any buffering. They provide buffering, but if you read from a pipe, you get whatever data is available, you don't have to wait for a buffer in the pipe. So the culprit would be the stdio buffering in the application.

Answer (score 3):

In a similar vein to [chad's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/11990), you can write a little script like this:

```
# save as ~/bin/scriptee, or so
script -q /dev/null sh -c 'exec cat > /dev/null'
```

Then use this `scriptee` command as a replacement for `tee`.

```
my-long-running-command | scriptee
```

Alas, I can't seem to get a version like that to work perfectly in Linux, so seems limited to BSD-style unixes.

On Linux, this is close, but you don't get your prompt back when it finishes (until you press enter, etc)...

```
script -q -c 'cat > /proc/self/fd/1' /dev/null
```

Comment: Why does that work? Does "script" turn off buffering?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: `script` emulates a terminal, so yes, I believe it turns off buffering. It also echoes back each character sent to it - which is why `cat` is sent to `/dev/null` in the example. As far as the program running inside `script` is concerned, it is talking to an interactive session. I believe it's similar to `expect` in this regard, but `script` likely is part of your base system.

Comment: The reason I use `tee` is to send a copy of the stream to a file. Where does the file get specified to `scriptee`?

Comment: @BrunoBronosky: You are right, it is a bad name for this program. It is not really doing a 'tee' operation. It is just disabling buffering of output, per the original question. Maybe it should be called "scriptcat" (though it's not doing concatenation either...). Regardless, you can replace the `cat` command with `tee myfile.txt`, and you should get the effect you want.

Answer (score 2):

`jq` has `--unbuffered` flag:

> Flush the output after each JSON object is printed (useful if you're piping a slow data source into jq and piping jq's output elsewhere).

Comment: A lot of tools have options like this but my question is really about how to fix that for *any* tool. I guess I'll have to file a feature request to GLIBC.

Comment: I don't see where OP mentions using `jq`.

Comment: Well... the other commenters aren't wrong, but *I'm* glad you mentioned jq's `--unbuffered` flag. I've just been trying to pipe the output of `mosquitto_sub` to `jq` in a Git Bash terminal. I'm troubleshooting a hardware problem, and I need a 'live' readout of a few values.  The messages that get splatted to the terminal are too big to see clearly, so I wanted to filter them using jq, got bit by this *exact same* buffering behavior. Using `jq --unbuffered` solved it neatly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Python has the `-u` (unbuffered) flag.

```
$ man python3
[...]
       -u     Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered.  This option has no effect on the stdin stream.
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this clever solution: `(echo -e "cmd 1\ncmd 2" && cat) | ./shell_executable`

This does the trick. `cat` will read additional input (until EOF) and pass that to the pipe after the `echo` has put its arguments into the input stream of `shell_executable`.

Comment: Actually, `cat` doesn't see the the output of the `echo`; you just run two commands in a subshell and the output of both is sent into the pipe. The second command in the subshell ('cat') reads from the parent/outer stdin, that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer/11947#11947), you could try reducing the pipe ulimit to one single 512-byte block. It certainly won't turn off buffering, but well, 512 bytes is way less than 4K :3

Comment: -1 **This is wrong.** The problem is the stdio buffering, _not_ the pipe buffering.

Answer (score -3):

According to [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-kernel/56380-how-alter-buffer-size-pipe.html) the pipe buffer size seems to be set in the kernel and would require you to recompile your kernel to alter.

Comment: I believe that is a different buffer.