# In terminal, I can search to end of log faster than the data gets there

Tags: shell, terminal, io, elisp

[The Question]
*Is there some way to have the pipe/tee/write combo write lines immediately? ... if it can be done, what is the  trade-off?*

[The Backdrop]
My script sends a keypress to the terminal, which is running `app`.
That keypress causes `app` to write a *marker* to its log.
The log is the *app's* normal screen output (timestamped lines).
The log is being written via `| tee -a log`

The marker *marks* the line I want; ie. the timestamped line *before* the marker.

The problem is that when I then *immediately* search the log (using `sed` from the same script), it sometimes returns a previous marker, ie. the most recent marker has not been written to the log yet.

I assume this is a buffering issue, but I'm in unknown territory  with that.

Not sure if it matters: The script is `elisp`. The terminal is  `emacs terminal emulator` with a `bash` shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the problem is not `tee` that I seem to remember do not buffer or at most buffers by lines.

So, if the problem is you `app`, you can modify its behavior using the `stdbuf` utility (unless `app` do its own modifications to stdout buffering). You can use it in this way:

```
stdbuf -o 0 app args | tee -a log
```

The `-o 0` option configures the stdout of `app` as unbuffered.

Comment: Thanks *enzo*. It sounds good, but unfortunately a version of coreutils with `stdbuf` isn't in my Ubuntu 10.04 repository... I'll look further into it tomorrow... +1 for now...

Comment: @ferer: see also this question: [Turn off buffering in pipe](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).

Comment: @ferer When you're running inside Emacs, you could run the application directly as a subprocess of Emacs and have Emacs write the log by periodically saving the output buffer.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks. If I've understood you correctly, you mean that I could run `app` without running it in the terminal... In this case I can't do that, because `app` is `mplayer`, and I would lose the ability to control it via its interactive response to key-presses.  
However, I've found a temporary(?) workaround..  
Each *marker* is unique, and because mplayer is constantly feeding the log, the buffer is flushed at a constant rate, so the problem occurs only for a short log (a long log takes longer to search). I've simply added a loop to repeat the search until the correct marker turns up.