# Flush 'tail -f' buffer?

Tags: pipe, tail

I'm using the following statement (simplified version):

```
tail -f -c+1 <filename>
```

in order to pipe a file to a process.

What I've found, though, is that there is a number of lines at the end which are not piped.

A specific example is piping a mysql file, and stopping when the end is reached:

```
tail -f -c+1 mysqdump.sql | sed '/^-- Dump completed/ q0'
```

This doesn't work - the last line of the dump `-- Dump completed [...]` is not piped to sed.

My guess is that the `tail -f` buffer, in this case, is flushed only when it's full.

Does anybody know how can I workaround this?

=================

I've found the cause - the description is not complete (and the code doesn't exhibit the behavior).

The problem happens when piping from a compressed (lzma) file:

```
tail -f -c+1 <filename.lzma> | lzma -d | sed '/^-- Dump completed/ q0'
```

Most likely, `tail` is not sending the last compressed block, because it doesn't detect any new line, as the input is binary.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295430/tail-f-log-log-grep-responsetime-cut-d-f-2 for an answer.

Comment: I don't understand your means.before tail and after tail what do you do?

Comment: and especially read the BashFAQ entry linked to in that stackoverflow question, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tail -f` flushes after every input line. You can confirm this with `strace` (or `truss` or whatever your unix variant provides to trace processes' system calls).

If there is an incomplete line, `tail -f` keeps waiting for the next newline. It's a tool designed for text files. If you need to tail a binary file (e.g. if `-- Dump completed` is not followed by a newline), you'll have to use a custom tool.

If you've redirected `sed`'s output away from the terminal, it will be doing its own buffering. Try [`stdbuf` or `unbuffer`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).

Comment: I was in fact executing on a binary file being remotely copied (I purposely don't want to use "ssh cat"). I worked the problem around using scp on a named pipe.

Comment: For `sed` you can use `-u` if you don't want buffer

Answer (score 4):

Example using `stdbuf -o0`. Reference: https://superuser.com/a/1123674/126847

```
tail -F cpu.log | stdbuf -o0 tr '=' ' ' | stdbuf -o0 awk '$6 > 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the command invoked in the question is that `sed` is invoked in buffering mode.

```bash
tail -f -c+1 <filename.lzma> | lzma -d | sed '/^-- Dump completed/ q0'
```

You need to add the `-u` flag:

```bash
tail -f -c+1 <filename.lzma> | lzma -d | sed -u '/^-- Dump completed/ q0'
```

For more info, read about the `-u` switch on the  `sed` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).