# Can't process stdout with pipe as it comes

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, fifo, tshark

I'm running tshark on a fifo, and the following is a bare example of a loop that prints the output of tshark **as it comes**:

```
tshark -i $fifo | while read line; do
    echo $line
done
```

The problem appears when I add filters to tshark. This example prints all `$line`s only after tshark exits (IP address is hidden):

```
tshark -i $fifo -T fields -e text -R '
    ip.src == **.**.***.**          &&
    http.response.code == 200       &&
    http.content_encoding == "gzip" &&
    http.content_type contains "text/html"
' | while read line; do
    echo $line
done
```

I have tried in other forms with no luck:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < <(tshark ...)

while read line; do
    echo $line
done <<<"$(tshark ...)"
```

Even grep prints the lines only after tshark ends:

```
tshark ... | grep .
```

I have tried running tshark without a pipe and the lines are printed correctly as they come. Why is the command after the pipe being feeded only after tshark exits?

**Additional details:** `| tee` works, but I get everything printed again when tshark exits, so it is not a good deal.

Comment: Hard to believe that a program's output shall depend on the program reading from the pipe... I would expect a buffering problem. But how should the receiving end influence this? Stupid as it sounds: Maybe tshark checks what's at the other side of the pipe? `strace` is your friend. What about cat (instead of tee)? And why is the output printed twice?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Definitely a buffering problem: `unbuffer tshark` worked! I read the man page for unbuffer, but I couldn't really understand the reasoning behind this... see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your `tshark` version has the `-l` option for (nearly) line-buffered output.

Comment: Right, this is the fix on the tshark part. Although, as I have shown in my own answer, if more than one pipe is going to be used, the others will have to be fixed too. As a simple example, `tshark -l ... | grep . | grep .` doesn't work, whereas `tshark -l ... | stdbuf -o 0 grep . | grep .` works, so all information on this thread was useful. Thanks everybody so much for all the help!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get it working with `stdbuf` from coreutils. Note that every command after the pipe requires the buffer to be adjusted too:

```
stdbuf -o 0 tshark -i $fifo -T fields -e text -R '
    ip.src == **.**.***.**          &&
    http.response.code == 200       &&
    http.content_encoding == "gzip" &&
    http.content_type contains "text/html"
' | 
stdbuf -o 0 sed 's/\\r\\n,\?/\n/g; s/\\t/\t/g' |
```

From the man page:

```
`stdbuf': Run a command with modified I/O stream buffering

(...)

`-o MODE'
`--output=MODE'
     Adjust the standard output stream buffering.
```

Comment: Why should every command after the pipe need adjustment, too?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Otherwise the output may get truncated. I got it truncated on the 80th line.

Comment: Great trick, but stdio buffering exists for a good reason, and it's lame that utilities which mess with stuff like `isatty()` force you to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Some utilities call isatty() to determine whether their output is a terminal and adjust their behaviour accordingly. `gzip` is a good example of this.

Try running it with `script(1)`:

> -c, --command command
>
> Run the command rather than an interactive shell.  This makes it easy
>   for a script to capture the output of a program that behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty.

If you run it like this:

```
script -c tshark -i $fifo -T fields -e text -R '
    ip.src == **.**.***.**          &&
    http.response.code == 200       &&
    http.content_encoding == "gzip" &&
    http.content_type contains "text/html"
' | while read line; do
    echo $line
done
```

You should be able to see lines come out live.

Comment: Thanks, but script requires something more. I get `script: invalid option -- 'i'`

Comment: Yo may need to put the entire command in quotes. Gets tricky with such a complex command. Try putting your entire call to tshark in a shell script, and then doing `script -c myscript.sh`.