# saving output of another command

Tags: shell, pipe, cat, tee

I need to select certain lines from the log file and also save them to a text file.
I tried the following but none of them are working as expected. The file "todel.txt" shows 0 bytes.

```
tail -f general.log | grep Some_word > >(tee -a todel.txt)

tail -f general.log | grep Some_word ; tee  todel.txt

tail -f general.log | grep Some_word | tee -a todel.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps "Some_word" is case sensitive? In which case you should use _grep -i_.

Comment: Are you sure, the required lines really appear there? By default `tail -f` will give you last 10 lines of input and whatever is written there unless the file is removed and recreated, in which case it quits. GNU `tail` has the `--retry` option which will wait until the file is recreated (although I think this option is non-POSIX).

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `stdbuf(1)` into your pipeline:

```
tail -f general.log | stdbuf -oL grep Some_word | tee -a todel.txt
```

This will set `grep`'s stdout stream buffering mode to be line-buffered, otherwise `grep` waits to get at least 4096 bytes from the stream (this is the default on Linux for buffered i/o).

Alternatively, you can also call `grep` with `--line-buffered`:

```
tail -f general.log | grep --line-buffered Some_word | tee -a todel.txt
```

See [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) and http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ for in-detail explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The third one should be working fine assuming that you have access to write files in the current directory.

For example: `tail -f general.log | grep "Some_word" | tee todel.txt`

That is properly-defined tee syntax. If it's not working, you're doing something else wrong.

Also, it's a good idea to put your search string in quotes. If you have a filename matching your search string in the current working directory, it may be considered a file argument instead of a search string.

Comment: I think you mean tee instead of tail in your command line example.

Comment: Sure enough. Thanks. What I get for multi-tasking.

Comment: Using `tail -f ... |grep` allows one to grep the new lines incoming (`-f` option to `tail`). AFAIK `grep` has no such option.

Comment: You're right. Wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Consider a text file with only a few characters in it.  If you run `tail -f...` and pipe it into the `grep | tee` machinery, you would end up in exactly the scenario of the question: `grep` would wait for more input before processing it, while `tee` does not receive anything at all.  Of course, if `general.log` is sufficiently large, the standard approach without altering the output buffer mode to line-buffered would work, but only if you it larger than the buffer size.  And then you would need to wait for filling up `grep`'s buffer again. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102505/50954

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks. had no idea that the default buffer was that large.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "my words" > mytextfile.txt
tail -f access.log > last_log.txt
tail -f access.log | grep "IP address" > hacker.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the lines you're looking for are being sent to [stderr instead of stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), in which case ending the line with `2>&1` should fix the problem:

```
tail -f general.log | grep Some_word | tee -a todel.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Why would `tail` send output to standard error?

Comment: Oh, good point.  I guess `2>&1` is just my reflexive answer to this type of question.

Comment: You might want to update your answer then. Plus your `2>&1` actually refers to `tee` in this case.