# ps only prints up to 4096 characters of any process's command line

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, procfs

When I grep for a java process I get below output but it's limited to 4096 characters which results to actual process name(which is kafka.Kafka) not shown in `grep` output.

Is this a limitation of grep?  Is there any way to print characters beyond 4096 limit?

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

> java -Xmx6G -Xms6G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
>   -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/x/kafka/data01/kafka-app-logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/x/kafka/data01/kafka-app-logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./../config/log4j.properties -cp :/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.5.0.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/connect-api-0.10.1.1.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/connect-file-0.10.1.1.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/connect-json-0.10.1.1.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-0.10.1.1.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/guava-18.0.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.6.3.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.6.3.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.3.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.3.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/javax.inject-1.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.22.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.22.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.22.2.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-4.9.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1.jar:/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1-so

Comment: can you refer this post.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101681/saving-output-of-another-command/102505#102505

Comment: That didn't solve the issue. I guess the limitation here is 4096 bytes.

Comment: when you say.. it didn't solve the issue... you get the same output ?

Comment: yep, got same output.

Comment: It looks like probably you could make your classpath a lot shorter by using wildcard syntax, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath/219801, or you can definitely move it (entirely) off the commandline using env var CLASSPATH; either of those has a good chance of making the commandline short enough to see your classname. Or for Java processes _only_, if your UID has access and you have or get JDK, `jps` shows classname regardless of commandline truncation (at least on Linux).

Comment: Also note that `/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar` is the same as `/x/home/bmcuser/kafka-paypal/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar`. The `..` means go back one directory

Comment: @slebetman I'm sure OP is aware but the script which probably generated this isn't

Comment: The title implies that `ps -ef` prints more, but *grep* is what's changing it. That seems... unfounded.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've submitted an edit to the title to fix that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is not a limitation of `grep`, but of `/proc/PID/cmdline` (technically, a design decision, not a limitation). `/proc/PID/cmdline` contains the complete command line of the process, with main command and arguments separated by ASCII NUL, and the file ends in NUL too. So, `grep` will print the whole file content if there is a match. (`ps -ef` gets the content of this file as `CMD`).

[The maximum length is hardcoded in the (Linux) kernel to the `PAGE_SIZE`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/base.c?v=3.14#L203):

```c
static int proc_pid_cmdline(struct task_struct *task, char * buffer)
{
        int res = 0;
        unsigned int len;
        struct mm_struct *mm = get_task_mm(task);
        if (!mm)
                goto out;
        if (!mm->arg_end)
                goto out_mm;    /* Shh! No looking before we're done */

        len = mm->arg_end - mm->arg_start;

        if (len > PAGE_SIZE)
                len = PAGE_SIZE;
```

hence 4096 bytes for such a system:

```
% getconf PAGE_SIZE
4096
```

Also, if you have multibyte character(s), the number of characters would be less than 4096, as you can imagine.

Comment: @zer0Id0l You can't change `PAGE_SIZE`: it's a property of the hardware. You'd have to design some new hardware with a larger page size, or (vastly easier…) remove the limitation that the content of `cmdline` is truncated to one page by implementing the proper memory mapping or copying.

Comment: FWIW, when Giles say it's a property of hardware he means it's the property of your CPU's MMU. So you need to use a CPU with MMU of page size larger than 4k or design an architecture (and build a motherboard+BIOS for it) that use external MMU with page size larger than 4k (remember, in the past MMU used to be an external chip) or design your own CPU (plus compiler etc). The other option is to modify the linux kernel so that `proc_pid_cmdline` does not use PAGE_SIZE

Comment: This design limitation doesn't need to exist. Feel free to write another proc_pid_cmdline that doesn't have it.