# pgrep -f matches on first 4096 characters only

Tags: pgrep

pgrep on a Ubuntu 19.10 matches on a cmd line of about 10000 characters just fine, but the same version (see below) of pgrep on Debian 10 (buster) greps only on the first 4096 characters.

Is there a way to make the Debian version match on the whole cmd line or would this require recompilation?

```
$ pgrep --version
pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.15
```

**Update** 'ps -ef' does not have the 4096 char limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ps only prints up to 4096 characters of any process's command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343353/ps-only-prints-up-to-4096-characters-of-any-processs-command-line)

Comment: Wouldn't help even if you recompiled `pgrep` - the limit comes from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

Comment: No, I was wrong: the limit is from `pgrep`: https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/commit/f9e56d3c667513d96b798340f7b7c1b40096f084

Comment: I noticed this limit of pgrep (and pkill) are affecting me on Fedora 31, too. It's quite frustrating. This limit of pgrep seems unnecessary, and I can't figure out a workaround other than editing the source and recompiling.