# Why isn't tee outputting to stdout?

Tags: logs, cp, stdout, tee

I'm using tmux and cueing up a very large copy:

```
/bin/cp -aRv /mnt/src/folder/. /mnt/dest/folder/ 2>&1 | tee /log/big_copy_log
```

When I run without `tee`, I see output on the terminal just fine. With tee, nothing shows in the logfile or screen. What am I missing?

- I don't mind stderr and stdout both going to the same log.
- I want to do this logging so I can audit later if necessary (multiple TB sized copy)
- The -a is because I'd like timestamps preserved, -R because there are multiple levels of folders to move, -v to log everything.
- I wasn't planning to use rsync, since this is designed to be a one-way copy.
- Using /bin/cp because cp is aliased.
- Tailing . on the src because I need all subfolders copied to dest folder

Comment: Try `2>&1` instead of `2&>1`.

Comment: Whoops, typo in the question syntax ... I'm using correct syntax in the actual command...

Comment: Oh wow, hang on, if you're copying multiple TB **use rsync**!

Comment: I was averse to using rsync because I wanted to only do things one way, not sync back to src from dest ...

Comment: Nothing when? Right away, or after the command has run (enough to fill up a flush a buffer or to completion)?

Comment: "I wasn't planning to use rsync, since this is designed to be a one-way copy" -- This doesn't make sense. `rsync` is one way. And `rsync` has the ability to write to a log file natively, meaning no need to use `tee`.

Comment: It is also faster, can compress while copying and is much, much better than `cp` at resuming unfinished transfers. The latter is particularly important when dealing with huge amounts of data. Basically, it is designed to solve all the issues you are asking about. Use it!

Comment: Thanks, I just used rsync. I did indeed understand it wrong. I appreciate the opportunity to learn.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101681/saving-output-of-another-command. SE needs a flag for "Solved through different means than originally asked, and thus this question remains (and likely will remain) unanswered."