# turn off buffering for `hping` in OpenBSD

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe, openbsd, output

It would appear that the output from [`hping`](http://ports.su/net/hping) is *fully buffered* when piped to `perl` for further line-by-line processing, so [piping hping to perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172028/awk-hping-print-difference-between-icmp-originate-receive) doesn't work.

> `hping --icmp-ts example.ca | perl -ne 'if (/Originate=(\d+) Receive=(\d+) Transmit=(\d+)/) { ($o, $r, $t) = ($1, $2, $3); } if (/tsrtt=(\d+)/) { print $r - $o, " ", $o + $1 - $t, "\n"; }'`

How do I change hping from being *fully buffered* to being *line buffered* when piped?

Not a duplicate of the following question, since no solution works in OpenBSD base:

[Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Comment: So `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` aren't available in BSD?

Comment: @slm `stdbuf` isn't in OpenBSD. `unbuffer` is, but it isn't immediately obvious: you need to install the `expect` port.

Comment: what, perl’s $|++ doesn’t work?

Comment: @user2497, can you clarify how exactly that'd be used?

Comment: @cnst In the perl block, before the if condition. perldoc perlvar.

Comment: @user2497, no, after removing `unbuffer`, replacing `if` with `$|++;if` makes no difference; I would imagine that it's because you can't change the buffering after the fact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [two common solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe), `stdbuf` and `unbuffer`.

`stdbuf` is from GNU coreutils, it was added in version 7.5 in 2009 so it has made its way to all current non-embedded Linux systems apart from CentOS 5. It is also in FreeBSD since version 8.4. No other unix variant has adopted it yet that I know of, and in particular not OpenBSD as of 5.4.

`unbuffer` is an [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script, and as such is available everywhere Expect is available, which includes pretty much any unix. All BSD variants have it in their port collection, in the `expert` package.

So install the `expect` package and run `unbuffer hping … | perl …`

Comment: Interestingly, OS X 10.8 on mid-2013 MacBook Air does include `expect version 5.45` in `/usr/bin/expect`, however, `unbuffer` seems to be missing.

Answer (score 3):

Another option may be to use `socat`:

```
# cf. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25377
socat EXEC:'hping --icmp-ts example.ca',pty,ctty STDIO | perl -ne 'if ...
```