# Using "ifne" in a pipeline – running multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

In my script, I am using the `ifne` utility from the [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package. The line can be simplified to the following:

```
printf "asdf\n" | ifne cat - && echo "stream not empty"
```

`ifne` executes only if the stream is non-empty. But how can I make the second command (`echo "stream not empty"`) also execute only if the stream is non-empty? For example, how can change the following command so that it doesn't print "stream not empty"?

```
printf "" | ifne cat - && echo "stream not empty"
```

Surrounding `cat` and `echo` with parentheses generates a syntax error:

```
printf "" | ifne (cat - && echo "stream not empty")
```

How can I execute the last command only if stream is non-empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifne` doesn't set an exit code based on whether the input is empty or not, so `&&` and `||` aren't going to work as hoped. An alternate approach to Babyy's answer is to use `pee` from the same package:

```
printf "asdf\n" | pee 'ifne cat -' 'ifne echo "stream not empty"'
```

This works like `tee`, but duplicates the input stream into a number of pipes, treating each argument as a command to run. (`tpipe` is a similar command, but behaves slightly differently.)

A possible issue though is that each of the commands may be writing to stdout in parallel, depending on buffering and length of input/output there is a chance that output will be interleaved, or vary from run to run (effectively a race). This can probably be eliminated using `sponge` (same package) instead of `cat`, and/or [other buffering/unbuffering solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe). It affects the example you gave, but may not affect your real use-case.

Comment: You're also likely to get a `Write error` by `tee` if the output is large or slow enough as `echo` (here a standalone `echo` executable), will exit immediately without reading its input, so `pee` will soon see a broken pipe.

Answer (score 9):

Use this format:

```
printf ""     | ifne sh -c  "cat - ; echo 'stream not empty' "
```

Output is none, and:

```
printf "bb\n" | ifne sh -c  "cat - ; echo 'stream not empty' "
```

Output is:

```
bb
stream not empty
```