# How to redirect stdout to a file and read from the same file simultaneously with another task?

Tags: bash, shell, files, io-redirection, stdout

I want to run a task (which takes quite a long time) remotely in Ubuntu Linux Bash via `nohup` and redirect `stdout` to a file, e.g.:

`nohup task > out.txt &`

From time to time I would like to check the progress of the task by looking into the output file:

`cat out.txt`

I haven't yet figured out how to do that because the file's content is shown as empty as long as the file is opened for writing by Bash.

So my question is:
Is there any linux command that allows a 'shared' `stdout` redirection?

Comment: A side note - the file will have some content before it is closed for writing. The amount of text appearing in this file is dependent on the filesystem used and configuration parameters - e.g. for `ext4` with default options it should be updated after every 4096 bytes written.

Answer (score 3):

> the file's content is shown as empty as long as the file is opened for writing by Bash.

That's not exactly what's happening. What's happening is that the task [buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) its output — it is accumulated in memory for a while, then written to the file in chunks. The in-memory buffer has a fixed size of a few kilobytes. This is done for performance, as each file write has a relatively high overhead. So you won't see your program's output at the beginning, but you will see it come piece by piece. This has nothing to do with bash.

If you want to see the output immediately, you can [start your program with](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/25375#25375) [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) (from the [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) software package). You trade performance for immediacy.

A second issue is that `cat` will show the output that has already been emitted, and exit as soon as it reaches the end of the file. If you want to keep reading output when it's appended, use [`tail`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix))'s follow mode.

```
nohup unbuffer task >out.txt &
tail -n +1 -f out.txt
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit `tail`. Instead of `tail`, you can use `less` and its follow mode (press `F`; press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop reading).

Comment: Very nice elaborate answer. I like the follow mode of `tail` and `unbuffer` works perfectly - also on OS X. So thanks a lot for that nice advice!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `tee` command, [here](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/) are some examples with it.

> The following command (with the help of tee command) writes the output both to the screen (stdout) and to the file.

```
$ ls | tee file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. I've realised that there is some error in the program that I wanted to run. Using stdout as usual, it will be shown immediately on the screen. But when redirecting it to a file it didn't. What I did is changing the source code of the program and as soon as the `cout` is used instead of `printf` the output was put into the file immediately. This is a behaviour I didn't anticipate. Maybe anyone knows the reason for that?

So `$ nohup task > out.txt &` works perfectly for my purpose. Nevertheless it's good to refresh the usage of good old `tee`

Comment: So the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499879/problem-redirecting-a-c-program-output-in-bash

Comment: @Wildkeiler I'm betting that in your `cout` version you used `endl` as well.  `endl` requests a buffer flush in addition to writing a newline.

Comment: Indeed `endl` not `cout` solved it.