# Using tee or pipe to log console output will cause my program not to start

Tags: pipe, raspberry-pi, raspbian, tee, hostapd

I'm running hostapd on my raspberry PI to let it function as an accesspoint. It's working fine with the following command:

`sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

This will start hostapd and log all output to the console. Now I want to log this output using TEE or pipe. However, one the following commands will cause the program not to start.

`sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf >> /home/pi/Desktop/loggin.txt
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf > /home/pi/Desktop/loggin.txt
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf | tee log.txt`

The terminal will just hang and I have to use ctrl-x to terminate. Why isn't this working? And how can I possibly fix this?

Comment: does `sudo` *anything* work that way? It should, but different `sudo` configs might not allow that if the terminal is not their outfile. And are you sure it is just *hanging* and not actually *working*?

Comment: What makes you think that the program isn't started? If it's only because you don't see any output, this could be because the program is executing normally, but its output is [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), so the output appears only in relatively large chunks. Try [unbuffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/25375#25375): `sudo unbuffer /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf | tee log.txt`, do you see output now?

Comment: It was actually running, but not working properly. However, I fixed it using the link @Gilles gave :)

Answer (score 2):

The command that made it work is:

```
sudo stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf | tee log.txt
```