# How to grep netcat output

Tags: grep, netcat

I'm trying to grep live text stream from `netcat`, but it doesn't work for me:

```
netcat localhost 9090 | grep sender
```

returns nothing, but I'm sure that it should.

If I redirect the `netcat` output to a file and add some delays (simulate real environment) - then it works:

```
$ (sleep 5; cat netcat_output; sleep 5) | grep sender

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"GUI.OnScreensaverDeactivated","params":{"data": "shuttingdown":false},"sender":"xbmc"}}
```

I also tried to add `--line-buffered` but w/o success.

What I do wrong?

Edit:

I noticed the same issue with `sed`, the output is empty.

But, for instance, `hexdump` converts text to hex live:

```
$ netcat localhost 9090 | hexdump -C
00000000  7b 22 6a 73 6f 6e 72 70  63 22 3a 22 32 2e 30 22  |{"jsonrpc":"2.0"|
00000010  2c 22 6d 65 74 68 6f 64  22 3a 22 50 6c 61 79 65  |,"method":"Playe|
00000020  72 2e 4f 6e 50 6c 61 79  22 2c 22 70 61 72 61 6d  |r.OnPlay","param|
00000030  73 22 3a 7b 22 64 61 74  61 22 3a 7b 22 69 74 65  |s":{"data":{"ite|
00000040  6d 22 3a 7b 22 69 64 22  3a 36 2c 22 74 79 70 65  |m":{"id":6,"type|
00000050  22 3a 22 6d 6f 76 69 65  22 7d 2c 22 70 6c 61 79  |":"movie"},"play|
00000060  65 72 22 3a 7b 22 70 6c  61 79 65 72 69 64 22 3a  |er":{"playerid":|
00000070  31 2c 22 73 70 65 65 64  22 3a 31 7d 7d 2c 22 73  |1,"speed":1}},"s|
```

Comment: Maybe it gets buffered in the pipe? You could try using `stdbuf -o0 netcat localhost 9090 | grep sender` (taken from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe))

Comment: Does it work like this ? `netcat -z localhost 9090 | grep sender`

Comment: @user43791 the output is still empty, but I'm sure that netcat returned matching string

Comment: @sputnick this one immediately returns to shell and doesn't wait for an event

Comment: There are no new lines in the hexdump, so `grep` is probably waiting endlessly for a newline. `cat` works since `grep` will get an EOF if not a newline, at least. Maybe try `awk` with `{` as RS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `read` command (`bash` builtin) to force characters to be read one by one :

```
netcat localhost 9090 | (
    cnt=0
    line=
    while read -N 1 c; do
        line="$line$c"
        if [ "$c" = "{" ]; then
            cnt=$((cnt+1))
        elif [ "$c" = "}" ]; then
            cnt=$((cnt-1))
            if [ $cnt -eq 0 ]; then
                printf "%s\n" "$line"
                line=
            fi
        fi
    done
) | grep sender
```

This script should print every full output with balancing `{`and `}`, but you can change the script to do whatever you want. This script would NOT do well on a benchmark compared to pretty much anything, but it's pretty simple and seems to work for me...

Note that your test sample didn't have matching `{`and `}`, so if this is the case of the real input, you might want to change the criteria to print the line.

Comment: Looks like the mismatching braces is just because he only posted the beginning of the output.

Answer (score 11):

Answer is here:
[grep not matching in nc output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219443/grep-not-matching-in-nc-output)

netcat outputs verbose logs to standard error, so we need to capture errors before we pipe to grep.

```
$ netcat -zv localhost 1-9000 2>&1 | grep succeeded
```

Comment: This answer just made me solution. That was very strange when I run that command without `2>&1`, it look like grep didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is the absence of newlines in the `netcat` output. I can see two workarounds:

1. Insert a newline every `x` seconds (with unfortunate consequences if the newline is inserted in the middle of `source`):

   ```
   ( while sleep 1; do echo; done & netcat ... ) | grep source
   ```
2. Use `awk` with an RS other than newline:

   ```
   netcat ... | awk -v RS='}' -v ORS='}' '/source/'
   ```

Comment: Still empty output. To make sure that command is correct I run on dumped stream -  `cat netcat_output | awk -v RS='}' -v ORS='}' '/sender/'` The output was ok:
`,"sender":"xbmc"}`

Comment: I just checked **first workaround and it works**! But as you mentioned it can split the output so it cannot be the final solution. Anyway many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `watch` command:

```
watch 'netcat localhost 9090 | grep sender'
```

Comment: It doesn't work too. The same with sed... But, for instance, this: netcat localhost 9090 | hexdump works and replace text to hex live, why?

Answer (score 0):

As per [@user43791 comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176498/how-to-grep-netcat-output/176698#comment291718_176498), try [disabling buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/21471), e.g.:

```
stdbuf -o0 netcat localhost 9090 | grep sender
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash you can use [pseudo-device files](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html) to open a TCP connection and grep it as usual. For example:

```
$ grep "sender" < /dev/tcp/example.com/1234
```

---

To test it, simply run server which can send some file, like:

```
$ nc -vl 1234 < /etc/hosts
```

Then in another terminal run the test to `grep` the output:

```
$ grep "127" < /dev/tcp/localhost/1234
127.0.0.1   localhost
```