# grep not matching in nc output

Tags: terminal, grep, netcat

I'm using `nc` to scan for open ports but I'm scanning a wide range and it's displaying too many results. Trying to `grep` it for the word "succeeded" doesn't work for some reason:

```
$ nc -zv localhost 31000-32000 | grep succeeded
...
nc: connect to localhost port 31957 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 31958 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 31959 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to localhost 31960 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
nc: connect to localhost port 31961 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 31962 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 31963 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 31964 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
...
```

*(I thought about sending the error messages to `/dev/null` as well: `nc -zv localhost 31000-32000 2>/dev/null`. But in that case there are no results whatsoever. It seems that all `nc` port status messages are error/debug messages)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`nc` writes its output to standard error, you need:

```
nc -zvv localhost 31000-32000 2>&1 | grep succeeded
```

The `2>&1` will redirect standard error to standard output so you can then pipe it to `grep`.

Comment: Why would it print to error??

Comment: @Gerard So as to not interfere with the data received from the server.