# grep not matching in nc output - tee gives no output

Tags: grep, netcat, tee

See original Q&A about grep not accepting netcat output on stderr at a [prior StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219443/grep-not-matching-in-nc-output/579108#579108).

Concise answer. I like it. Why does adding a tee on the end fail to produce any output?

```
nc -zvv localhost 3100-3200 2>&1 | grep succeeded | tee test.txt
```

Using only tee works.
Using only grep works.
Chaining tee after grep gives no output (console or file).

Any ideas?

Comment: I could not recreate your result on my system. "It works for me fine" :(
Please consider adding some more details. Maybe it is system specific?
My version of software answers with "open" `localhost [127.0.0.1] 22 (ssh) open
localhost [127.0.0.1] 21 (ftp) : Connection refused`, and you seems to expect "succeeded"

Comment: @DevilaN When a connection _is_ established, `grep` will not output anything until 1) its output buffer is full, or 2) `nc` terminates.  The issue is with buffering, and you can turn this off by using `grep --line-buffered` (with `grep` implementations that support this non-standard option). The buffering is there for performance reasons, and happens when the output of `grep` is not a terminal (it's a pipe in the example in the question).

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes, but `nc` is running with example command from OP in under 1 second, so I thought that waiting for buffer is no issue in this case.

Comment: @DevilaN Do you know what service the `nc` is connecting to when the user in the question is using that command? I.e. what's running on the specified ports? We can assume that it is not responding with `Connection refused`, because the user says that there is no output.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I thought that `nc -zvv` is not waiting for any service output but only connects to find out whether there is port open. To think of now, there might be some app, that is not doing `accept()` right away and this might be a reason for long scan, but this seems to be very unusual situation (but not impossible).

Comment: @DevilaN So it is. My apologies. I was too quick to react to the pipe from `grep` at the end. I have reopened the question. The answer is probably that there simply isn't anything listening to the ports in the given range, or that my initial closeing as a dupe was correct because they aren't showing the actual command that they used.

Comment: if this indeed a buffering issue the OP could use ```unbuffer``` (usually from the package 'expect') in order to disable buffering for this command sequence.

Answer (score 0):

DevilaN, Kusalananda,

Thank you. It was a combination of my impatience and grep and nc behavior. Using the command below on my Raspberry Pi,

```
nc -nvw1 127.0.0.1 1-65535 2>&1 | grep succeeded | tee test.txt
```

All the ports were scanned, ~then~ the console printed out 6 open ports.  When I used the --line-buffered option, the command behaved as I expected (printing as they were found).

Also, the buffering behavior of grep apparently happens only when piped into tee. When tee is not used and the --line-buffered is not used, grep still prints out the open ports as found.

Without the -w1 option, the first open port is printed on the console by grep, but then the output hangs - actually it's the output of nc that hangs in this case.

Comment: `grep` buffers as soon as its output is not written to a terminal. The fact that it is `tee` after the pipe is irrelevant, it's the fact that the output is piped that matters.