# Expose awk over tcp (inetd, socat, etc.)

Tags: awk, socat

I was playing around with awk, and I wanted to expose it over a tcp socket.

At first I tried, but failed with micro-inetd. Thinking that maybe the issue could be in the way that carriage returns/newlines characters are handled, I decided to try to switch to socat.

Using a remote command with socat is easy enough:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 EXEC:/bin/cat
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 SYSTEM:"/bin/python -i"
```

both of these work

But when trying the same with a simple awk command (for example `awk '{print NR}' to progressively count the number of lines received) I don't get anything back when connecting with socat from another shell on the same machine.

I tried plenty of things (some of these fail with a syntax error that is a bit obscure to me. I cannot even try to strace socat to see what exactly is being executed, since the actual command exec'ing is delegated to the shell):

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 SYSTEM:"/usr/bin/awk '{print NR}'"
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 SYSTEM:'/usr/bin/awk "{print NR}"'
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 SYSTEM:'/usr/bin/awk "{print\ NR}"'
```

I also created a small script `/tmp/testawk`

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/awk '{print NR}'
```

(also with an exec variant)

```
#! /bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/awk '{print NR}'
```

Both of these work locally, but when invoking

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 EXEC:/tmp/testawk
```

It doesn't send me back the output

Thinking that the issue might be inheritance of the stdin/stdout handles and/or again handling of crlf... I tried also with:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 EXEC:/tmp/testawk,nofork
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000,crnl EXEC:/tmp/testawk
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 EXEC:/tmp/testawk,crnl
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000,crnl EXEC:/tmp/testawk,crnl
```

I've found someone else who complained about [a similar issue](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1744534), but apparently it failed to garner any attention

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `socat` to associate a pty with the `awk` program; this forces `awk` to run in line buffered mode and you get the immediate responses you're looking for.

Here's the command line to listen on port 9000:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000 SYSTEM:'/tmp/awk.sh',pty,echo=0
```

And here's the contents of the script `/tmp/awk.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#
BEGIN   { print "This is the awk socket" }
        { print NR, $0 }
END     { print "All done" }
```

Sample run:

```
$ nc -vvv otherhost 9000
otherhost [192.168.1.15] 9000 (?) open
This is the awk socket
hello world
1       hello world
how are you
2       how are you
boo
3       boo
^C sent 28, rcvd 61
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk is printing to standard output, which is line buffered when it points to a terminal, and fully buffered if not; this means you should get output after it fills the buffer, ie it has printed (eg) 4KB.

You can test this by sending a lot of output (eg using the yes program); to fix you should either:
- unbuffer awk's stdout (see eg https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375/63847)
- use the shutdown(2) system call from the sender (ugly)

Any better solution is welcome

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, but overlooked it when playing around with different options. Anyhow I tried with `stdbuf -oL -eL /usr/bin/awk '{print NRq}'` but I still cannot see anything from the other side

Comment: The `pty` option apparently was what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344501/make-socat-write-to-tcp-or-unix-socket-line-by-line-for-log-gathering