# Using GNU timeout when redirecting stdout to file

Tags: stdout, timeout

Suppose I have a executable which for which I want to log STDOUT and STDERR to separate files, like so:

```
python write.py > out 2> err
```

When I use this command with GNU `timeout`, my `out` file is always empty.  Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

```
timeout 5s python write.py > out 2> err
```

---

Example write.py:

```
#!/bin/bash
import sys, time

i = 0
while True:    
    print i
    print >> sys.stderr, i
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ timeout 5s python write.py > out 2> err
$ ls -l out err
-rw-r--r-- 1 yeti yeti 10 Apr  6 08:12 err
-rw-r--r-- 1 yeti yeti  0 Apr  6 08:12 out
$ timeout 5s python -u write.py > out 2> err
$ ls -l out err
-rw-r--r-- 1 yeti yeti 10 Apr  6 08:13 err
-rw-r--r-- 1 yeti yeti 10 Apr  6 08:13 out
$ cmp err out && echo same
same
$ cat out 
0
1
2
3
4
```

`python` uses buffered writes on `stdout` but not on `stderr`. So everything written to `sys.stderr` is written immediately but stuff for `sys.stdout` is kept in a buffer until the buffer is full to minimise write operations. Within 5 seconds, the buffer does not fill enough to get written even once and `timeout` terminates the `python` interpreter.

Adding the `-u` option to `python`'s invocation, writes to `stdout` will be unbuffered too.

You can force the same behaviour for a Python program by setting the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`. For other programs you can use [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) from the [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) package or [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#stdbuf-invocation) from [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (see [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)).

Comment: So this problem actually came up in the context of a different executable (not Python), do you know a more general solution? if it helps, the executable was a `make` compilation using Scala's `sbt`.

Comment: @dal102 `unbuffer` or `stdbuf` (see my edit)