# Can I disable buffering for tr

Tags: tr

`tr` seems to buffer its input so that this command `LongRunningCommand|tr \\n ,` will only start producing output after a few kilobytes of input from LongRunningCommand have accumulated.

Is there a way to force `tr` to stop this buffering or any other command that can replace new-lines with an other character without buffering?

---

P.S. I've already tried the first two suggestions from [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) without success.

Comment: did you apply `stdbuf` to LongRunningCommand or to tr, or to both, differently?

Comment: To both like this: `stdbuf -o0 fping -aAq -r2 -g 10.30.0.1 10.30.0.255 2>/dev/null | stdbuf -i0 tr \\n ,`

Comment: `fping -q` says "Don't show per-probe results, but only the final summary", so perhaps it only does one long write at the end?

Comment: No the fping command works fine by itself. Many thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: I think the buffering problem is actually in the *output* of `tr`. Try `|stdbuf -i0 -o0 tr ...`

Comment: `awk '{ printf "%s,", $0 }'` will run with no buffering (aside from the fact that it processes only complete lines of input).

Comment: @meuh it's indeed the buffering at the **output** of tr -- I feel silly! -- please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, your awk mini-script also works just fine! Please post an answer so that I can upvote it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Commands generally don't buffer their input. They would do a `read()` for a large chunk, but when reading from a pipe, if there aren't that many bytes in the pipe, the `read()` system call will return with as many characters there are and the application will generally work with that if it can.

A notable exception to that is `mawk` which will keep re-`read()`ing until the input buffer is full.

Applications do buffer their *output* (stdout) though. The usual behaviour is that if the output is going to a tty, then the buffering will be line-wise (that is, it won't start writing to stdout until it has a full line to output, or a block-full for very long line), while for every other type of file, the buffering is by blocks (that is, it won't start writing until is has one block full to write (something like 4KiB/8KiB... depends on the software and system)).

So in your case `LongRunningCommand` likely buffers its output by blocks (since its output is a pipe and not a tty), and `tr` likely buffers its output by line since its output is probably the terminal.

But, since you remove every newline character from its output, it will never output a line, so the buffering will be by block.

So here you want to disable buffering for both `LongRunningCommand` and `tr`. On GNU or FreeBSD systems:

```
stdbuf -o0 LongRunningCommand | stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' ,
```

Note that if you want to join the lines with a comma, a better approach is to use `paste -sd , -`. That way the output will be terminated by a newline character (you'll probably still need to disable buffering).

Comment: @mikeserv. Yes, and one that uses stdio buffering and doesn't call setvbuf/setbuffer... by itself and is not a shell builtin. But generally on GNU and FreeBSD systems, all those conditions are satisfied.

Comment: oh. i only learned that myself a few days ago when i was disappointed that i couldnt affect the i/o streams for my statically compiled `sed`. sorry if it was annoying - but i didnt realize it was general knowledge. i guess it uses LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation of what happens Stéphane. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

To replace newlines with `","`, you can run

```
awk '{ printf "%s,", $0 }'
```

GNU awk (`gawk`) and Solaris `nawk` will run with line buffering on stdin and no buffering stdout when the output is to a terminal. If your awk is `mawk`, which happens on Ubuntu, you can give it the `-W interactive` option to get that same buffering behavior.