# Avoid output buffering for a command group (curly braces) in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, buffer

I have a bash script containing a group of commands in curly braces `{ ... }`. This group contains some initial `echo` commands and then *one loop*. At each iteration the loop executes various *slow* commands (basically with `curl` and some extra parsing). Each iteration is slow (because of network interaction) but it prints one line (of python code); as far as I can see, there should be no buffering issue coming from the commands themselves because they terminate their job and leave.

The whole group of commands is piped to `python -u` (I also tried with `tail -f` in order to check) and obviously the whole loop is executed before anything is read by `python -u` or `tail -f`.

I know how to unbuffer (when possible) *one* command with various tools like `stdbuf` but I don't think it can help here because it looks like the issue comes from the command-grouping rather than from such or such command.

Any hint?

Comment: I would still try unbuffering between the close brace and the next command.

Comment: Agreed. I think the culprit is the pipe, not the braces.

Comment: @TomZych - nope, it's not the pipe. programs don't typically buffer input - and it is really *weird* when they do. they buffer *output* when it is not written to a terminal.

Comment: Command grouping has no impact on any buffering, so you're looking in the wrong place. Show us your code.

Comment: Note to future readers: @mikeserv was right, I was wrong. It wasn't the pipe. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note to future readers: the tone of exasperation here is not for the question, but for the mistakes I made trying to answer it and the multiple edits they entailed.)

Oh, for pity's sake. The problem is in `tail -f`. This works just fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'hi\n'
{
    for i in 1 2 3 4; do
        sleep 0.5
        /bin/echo $i
    done;
} | cat
printf 'bye\n'
```

It's not the pipe, it's not the group. It's `tail`. As in, chasing our own tails!

So, `tail -f` failed because it doesn't output right away for some reason. Not sure why `python -u` is failing, but I don't think it's anything in the script. Maybe try `unbuffer` with it. Try your script with `cat`, at least, and verify that it's unbuffered in that case.

---

**Earlier failed attempt intentionally left here so future readers can make sense of the comments.**

This script exhibits the same kind of buffering problem you're getting:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'hi\n'
{
    for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    sleep 0.5
    printf '%s\n' $i
    done;
} | tail -f
printf 'bye\n'
```

This one does not. Output inside the group is redirected to stderr, then stderr from the whole group is piped to the command. Since it's stderr, it's unbuffered.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'hi\n'
{
    for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    sleep 0.5
    printf '%s\n' $i 1>&2
    done;
} |& tail -f
printf 'bye\n'
```

Adapted from Wang HongQin's answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372). The difficulty was in finding a way to unbuffer the pipe with braces rather than an explicit command. Had to fiddle around a while to get the redirection working properly.

Comment: Hummm... You actually see very well the issue. I see the idea (and I also read the original post by Wang HongQin), but after having tried your very own example by using `printf 'print %s\n' $i` and by replacing `tail -f` by `python -u`, it looks like the `print` statements are getting displayed without being read by python. I don't think the output is really piped, though it _looks_ like it is (since `tail -f` is supposed to print something on the screen which happens to be the case here). I am pretty sure that `tail` in your example doesn't get anything.

Comment: Yes, sorry, stuff was going out via stderr. I realized it after I posted and had to delete while I worked it out. Revision should work.

Comment: Don't be sorry; I learn much here ;-) But I still don't think that the new version actually works :-( Could you try with `python -u` and by replacing your four numbers by a valid python `print` statement?

Comment: Sigh, no, you're right. I had turned off the `sleep` for testing and forgot to make sure that output was unbuffered. I have RL stuff now and can't work on this. I'll leave it up, maybe someone else can start from here and work out the bugs.

Comment: these examples are not at all pertinent to the question, unless your `printf` is `/bin/printf` *(though i would doubt it even in that case)*. the shell doesn't do output buffering in the same way most programs do, and `sleep` doesn't buffer writes at all because it doesn't do any.

Comment: @mikeserv: The `sleep` was just to delay things so I could tell whether it was buffering or not. The `printf` issue occurred to me too, so I changed it to `/bin/echo` for future testing. Haven't solved it yet, though. I don't see a way to pipe `stderr` directly and I suspect this whole approach is unworkable. Trying something else now. Using `stdbuf -o0 /bin/echo` failed too.

Comment: the problem is not in `tail -f` *exactly* - it does what you'd expect for a program that has to read the same file over time even though its already reached end of file over and over - it loops over it. obviously its not going to check the file for new information *all of the time* - that would be terribly wasteful - the typical `tail -f` implementation checks every 60 seconds.

Comment: You are perfectly right with your `cat` proof; thus my issue obviously comes from the behaviour of `python -u` which doesn't seem to parse its stdin as unbuffered.

Comment: I am not sure that the code with `cat` "works" for the reason you think. This code `{ echo foo >> mylog; echo bar; echo foo >> mylog } | cat >> mylog` creates `mylog` with lines foo, foo, bar, indicating that what was piped to `cat` was buffered. On the other hand, `{ echo foo >> mylog; echo bar; sleep 0.5; echo foo >> mylog } | cat >> mylog` produces `mylog` with lines foo, bar, foo. This suggests that somehow `sleep` flushes the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to do:

```
{   stdbuf -o0 curl ...
    stdbuf -o0 whatever ...
}|  tail -f
```

...which will work for dynamically linked applications, though i'm pretty sure `curl` includes its own *unbuffer* switch of some kind.