# "cut" hangs when using "tail -f" in combination with "tr"

Tags: shell, tail, cut

I'm try to pipe chat log files to some speech output, and want to remove timestamps with `cut` and remove special characters with `tr`. Unfortunately, `cut` seems to halt when using it with `tail -f` in combination with `tr`:

```
//works
$ tail /path/to/chatlogs | cut -b18- 
test
test

//works, too
$ tail /path/to/chatlogs | tr -C -d  '[:alnum:][:cntrl:] '
test
test

// does not work
$ tail -f /path/to/chatlogs | tr -C -d  '[:alnum:][:cntrl:] ' | cut -b18-
//no output
```

Why? How can I work around this?

---

It even hangs when piping two times into `cut`:

```
$ tail -f file | cut -b5- | cut -b5-
//no output
```

Comment: hmmm... your *works* example seems to be identical to your *does not work* example. if there is a problem with `tail -f` it might have to with its checking for new input only every 60 seconds or so. if it were to try to `open()` the file all the time it would eat a lot of resources. try `while <file; do :; done` here *`<file`* is some regular, readable file, in the terminal and have a look at `top` in another terminal while it runs. or `: >file; until read v; do : ; done <file`.

Comment: The second `tail` command waits for additional input because of the follow (-f) switch and never exits.

Comment: What Lambert said; why are you using `-f` if you don't want it to wait for more output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax you use only processes new input on `/path/to/chatlogs`. Try to run the command and log a new entry in `/path/to/chatlogs` and see what the output is or try:

```
tail -1000f /path/to/chatlogs | tr -C -d  '[:alnum:][:cntrl:] ' | cut -b18-
```

to have the last 1000 lines also processed.

The 'hanging' part is actually the `tail` process which is waiting for further input to be passed through the pipe.

To disable buffering from the `tr` command use:

```
tail -f /path/to/chatlogs | stdbuf -i0 -oL tr -C -d  '[:alnum:][:cntrl:] ' | cut -b18-
```

The above is used from [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple pipes, I'm running into stdio buffering issues.

The problem is described in detail at http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ and there does not seem to be a solution.

Comment: See my updated answer about buffering.