# Using 'ping', 'cut' and 'tee' together

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

So, I understand that by using 'tee' I can redirect the output of a command such as 'ping' to stdout as well as a file.

For example:

```
> ping google.com | tee somefile
```

This would display the ping statistics on terminal and write them to 'somefile'.

Now, if I wish to modify the output from 'ping', I can use 'cut' in such a way:

```
> ping google.com | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

But, if I wish to use all the three commands together, I get a no output on stdout and an empty file.

```
> ping google.com | cut -d' ' -f 1 | tee somefile
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? Somehow I feel I am not using 'tee' properly. Any insight would be appreciated.

I'm using bash shell, if this is relevant.

Comment: You're simply not waiting long enough; eventually the pipe buffer fills up and dipslays the output.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I thought I wasn't waiting long enough, but after a couple of minutes, I realized that that wasn't the problem. Thanks for the link though, it addresses the issue I am facing precisely. But, the solutions provided involve installing a new package. I was hoping for a more generic solution without installing external packages.

Comment: My bad, the inbuilt `stdbuf` works perfectly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your pipe commands, as a non-terminal destination, are buffering your output. It will show up eventually, but only when quite a lot of output builds up or the ping command exits.

You can use `ping -c 5 google.com` to set a specific number of packets to be sent and then ping will exit. Your output comes back and the pipes should work as expected.

Edit: another workaround uses `stdbuf` to avoid pipe buffering and `awk` to avoid some internal `cut` buffering and lets the ping run continuously:

```
ping www.google.com | stdbuf --output=0 awk '{print $1}' | tee /tmp/file
```

Comment: You are correct, I tried it with count specified, and it did display the result on stdout and in the file. However, if I don't specify the count and kill the process by using Ctrl-C, would I still see the output? Or would all of it be lost because of the interrupt?

Comment: If you hit ^C from the terminal, the interrupt signal would be sent to the last command you ran-- the `tee` so you would not get the output. Now you could be sneaky and find the PID of the ping command itself then use `kill -INT <PID>` and **ONLY** the ping command would stop and the output would be sent to `cut` and `tee`, letting you see it.

Comment: Ah! Killing the long_running_process (ping) did the job. Thanks! However it does seem sort of a workaround. The link provided by @Jeff above describes the need to _unbuffer_ the output. But the only built-in command `stdbuf` doesn't work with `tee` :/. Are there better ways to format and (print the output and write to file) ?

Comment: On my linux test host, there seems to be something "special" about `cut` in particular. I tried the same test using `awk '{print $1}'` and the no-output problem went away. Perhaps `cut` is buffering things internally too? `ping www.google.com | stdbuf --output=0 awk '{print $1}' | tee /tmp/file` Note that the output to "file" will still be buffered.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I think I wasn't using `stdbuf` correctly. Your solution works as expected. Interestingly, when I tried `awk`, my output was still buffered, it was displayed/written in chunks. However when I used `cut` it wasn't the case. The output was displayed line by line. So to me it seems that `awk` is buffering whereas for you it is the opposite. Strange I must say. Or maybe I'm missing something crucial..

Comment: The problem with command internal buffering is you never know what will work where. For a portable solution, whipping up a quick Python or Perl script to read, parse, and output using buffering of your own choice might be the best option. If you only need it to work on that one system, you're already done!