# How do I use multiple options for grep (on live output)?

Tags: grep

For example, when I do this

```
sudo tcpdump | grep -E '.dev:8888|ads' | grep -v 'adsl'
```

ALL output is suppressed for some reason, nothing is shown if I access `ads.google.com` for example, it does show when I remove the `grep -v`, so the base command works.

However, If I try to make a file containing:

```
test
test2
```

and do `grep -E 'test|test2' | grep -v 'test2'` I get my desired output (`test`). So what is the difference when it's constantly updating, and how would I use multiple options with `grep` to modify the output?

Comment: I know this will sound really strange butdid you try using `grep -e ".dev:8888" -e ads` instead of `grep -E '.dev:8888|ads'` ?

Comment: @MelBurslan that works in the same way. Working, but when I add `| grep -v 'adsl'` no output is shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have a problem with line-buffering here. Instruct `tcpdump` and the intermediate `grep` command(s) to line-buffer their outputs as follows:

`sudo tcpdump -l | grep --line-buffered -E '.dev:8888|ads' | grep -v 'adsl'`

See also [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) for general solutions when these command options are not available.