# netcat doesn't print response

Tags: pipe, netcat

I'm trying to send commands to a tcp port using `netcat` and pipe response
when I run `netcat` and type my command it prints response correctly but when I pass command from a pipe it sends the command correctly but doesn't print response

So, this works correctly:

```
netcat  localhost 9009
```

while this just sends command but doesn't print response:

```
echo 'my_command' | netcat  localhost 9009
```

why?
How can I make `netcat` to print response text ?

Comment: [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) is probably happening to you

Comment: @JeffSchaller: no! unfortunately using those commands doesn't help! this time it blocks forever!

Comment: Which netcat are you using? Unfortunately there's a dozen different variations of the netcat tool, and they don't all behave the same. Also, what is on the remote end?

Comment: @Patrick: my netcat is `OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.105-7ubuntu1)` version; and at the remote end is `telegram-cli` on the same machine.

Comment: I think I found a man page for that netcat, but I don't see any flags which would control what I suspect is happening. I suspect that once `netcat` receives the EOF on STDIN, that it immediately shuts down both sides of the socket instead of doing a half-close and waiting for the remote side to close its end. If `socat` is an option, I would highly recommend it instead. There's only one `socat`, so you don't have the portability issues with there being a dozen different flavors of it, it behaves a lot more sanely, and is highly configurable.

Comment: @Patrick: thanks; I tried `socat` and same thing happens with it !!! interesting point is that both netcat & socat in using piped input exit immediately while in interactive mode it takes a time to get response; second, some `telegram-cli` commands work correctly (e.g. `help`); actually it seems commands that need to communicate over network has this problem!

Comment: Try adjusting the `-t` option of `socat`. If that doesn't solve it, I'd look at an strace or a packet capture then. It's likely that the issue is the remote (`telegram-cli`) end, and it shutting down the connection as soon as it receives the EOF reading from the client, even if it has pending responses to write.

Comment: @Patrick: changing `-t` had no effect!

Comment: The difference is that the first variant is waiting for more input on `stdin`, while the second variant terminates `stdin` as soon as `echo` has finished. I guess `netcat` terminates once it sees EOF on `stdin`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Patrick said, this problem is usually due to `netcat` exiting before the response has been given. You remedy that by adding `-q 2` to the command line, i.e., tell `netcat` to hang around 2 seconds after detecting EOF on standard input. Obviously you can make it wait some other number of seconds as well.

Comment: Thanks; `-q 2` worked but is it trust-able? it is making web request I can't be sure 2s is always enough! can I ?

Comment: Use a larger number to make it wait longer, or some negative number to make it wait indefinitely. There's also the `-w` option to play with. This is all in the `man nc` page of course.

Comment: it says `invalid option -- 'q'`

Comment: I think a good follow-up question is: why is `nc` exiting immediately instead of waiting for a response?  If the connection is still open, there should be an option to make `nc` wait for it to close, not just for stdin to end

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I used `--no-shutdown` and it works.

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
cat <(echo command) - | nc host port
```

The problem is that `nc` will close the connection immediately after stdin is closed, which is very quick for a simple `my_command` string, and thus never gets the chance to receive a response. (If you pipe a very large file you will see that it might get a response before it's done sending the file).

Enter `cat` with `-` as second argument: It makes `cat` listen on stdin for more content to pipe through after it has sent the contents of the first argument. The first argument is just getting the `echo` command through `cat` – it could also be a file with your commands a la `cat < file - | ...`.

Alternatively do this:

```
(echo command; while true; do sleep 0.01; echo -n "#"; done) | nc host port
```

This sends unlimited `#` characters on the 2nd line of the input. Using `#` works for a bash like remote that would ignore this as a comment. I chose a small wait time of 10 milliseconds here, so it reacts faster on connection end. YMMV.

The downside of that can be that `cat` or the `while` loop and `nc` keep running until you hit `^C` or `^D` on the shell. It really depends on the remote end.

Adding a timeout using `-w 1` (OSX netcat) or `-i 1` (nmap's ncat) makes it close the connection and `nc` after 1 second, but `cat` will keep running until you enter some character and the pipe breaks (I think).

However, it works if the remote side will automatically close the connection after receiving and handling the command - this will also end the `nc` client and the process piping into it.

This answer is based on this [this answer to an identical superuser question](https://superuser.com/a/410642/40989).

Comment: `{ echo my_command; cat;}` would do the same and might be considered to be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Different openbsd-netcat versions are quirky, needing different combinations of `-w <seconds>`, `-q <seconds>`, `-N` and even need different arguments depending on what is running on the other end of the connection. Using timeout options with certain versions or servers cause delays, and not using them might result in an extremely long (infinite?) delay. And I would expect different quirks with gnu netcat, but don't know if they are different between versions of it.

For example version 1.130_3 from archlinux takes extremely long (forever?) when I do this:

```
$ echo response | nc -l 9999 &
[1] 15190

$ time echo request | nc localhost 9999
request
response

(wait forever possibly)
```

But it works with -N added to either the server or the client.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but no other answer worked for me and this did:

```
echo 'test' | netcat -N $server $port
```

Notice the `-N`:

> shutdown the network socket after EOF on the input.  Some servers require this to finish their work.

Worked for me on both Windows and Linux.

Note: This is a copy paste of the answer I posted for a [duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332163/netcat-send-text-to-echo-service-read-reply-then-exit).

I'm thinking this could be useful. Mods feel free to edit / delete if this is against policy or something.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the ncat from nmap.

```
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
```

The --no-shutdown option solves this issue:

```
echo 'test' | netcat --no-shutdown $server $port
```