# netcat: send text to echo service, read reply then exit

Tags: echo, netcat

I would like to use `netcat` to send a piece of text to the echo service on my server, get the reply then exit, so that I know the connection is still good. so far I've tried:

```
 echo 'test' | netcat server 7
```

this way netcat would wait for more input rather than exit.

How can I make `netcat` exit after getting reply from the echo service?

Comment: Netcat is buggy - the problem is that doing this correctly is not so simple as it seems.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289364/netcat-doesnt-print-response

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just tried - slightly different behaviour between `netcat-openbsd` and `netcat-traditional` ( ubuntu 16.4). The OpenBSD variant does what you expect, while with the netcat-traditional I need to add the `-q 1` to avoid waiting for more input.

```
echo 'test' | netcat -q 1 server 7
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a bit old but no other answer worked for me and this did:

```
echo 'test' | netcat -N $server $port
```

Notice the `-N`:

> shutdown the network socket after EOF on the input.  Some servers require this to finish their work.

Worked for me on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
cat <(echo command) - | nc host port
```

The problem is that `nc` will close the connection immediately after stdin is closed, which is very quick for a simple `my_command` string, and thus never gets the chance to receive a response. If you pipe a very large file you will see that it might get a response before it's done sending the file.

Enter `cat` with `-` as second argument: it makes `cat` listen on stdin for more content to pipe through after it has sent the contents of the first argument. The first argument is just getting the `echo` command through `cat` – it could also be a file with your commands a la `cat < file - | ...`.

The downside of that is now that it stays open until you hit `^C` or `^D` on the shell. Adding a timeout using `-w 1` (OSX netcat) or `-i 1` (nmap's ncat) makes it close the connection after 1 second, but it won't exit the process until you enter some character.

This answer is based on [this answer to an identical superuser question](https://superuser.com/a/410642/40989).

Comment: `cat <(echo command) <(sleep 1) | nc host port` causes stdin to stay open as long as the `sleep` command runs without the need to set nc timeouts or have the user "enter some character".

Answer (score 6):

Your command should work. It is very similar to some of the examples in the `netcat` manpage.

This is exactly how `netcat` is supposed to operate: once it has reached EOF on stdin, it (one-way) closes the connection /to/ the server and then waits for data coming from the server. When the latter closes the connection (the other way: server->client), then `netcat` stops.

If your `netcat` command doesn't finish, I suppose there is something strange happening at the network level that keeps the `echo` server listening for additional input.

You can try out the `-q` option to force `netcat` to stop N seconds after EOF is encountered on stdin:

```
netcat -q1 server echo <<< "test"
```

(`<<< "test"` is a `bash`ism, use your `echo ... |` syntax if you don't use `bash`)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your question properly?

The default netcat listener should exit upon receiving input (in this case your echo pipes it to netcat which forwards it to the listener).

If you want the listening Netcat service to stay listening after it receives input:

```
nc -lk 12345
```

- where 12345 is the port number

Most importantly though, please check the man pages for netcat.. they are amazingly useful for all commands...

```
man nc
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend `socat` instead:

```
echo test | socat -t 10 - tcp:server:7
```

(here waiting for up to 10 seconds for the server to reply and shutdown)

`socat` can do much much much more than the various (different and incompatible) implementations of `nc`/`netcat`, and generally works more reliably. It's your ultimate plumbing Swiss Army knife.

Quoting the man page for the `-t` option:

> -t<timeout>
>     When one channel has reached EOF, the write part of the other channel is shut down. Then, socat waits  [timeval] seconds
>                 before  terminating. Default is 0.5 seconds. This timeout only applies to addresses where write and read part can be closed independently. When during the timeout interval the read part gives EOF, `socat` terminates without awaiting the timeout.

So above, after `echo` writes `test\n`, it exits, which closes the pipe. `socat` sees EOF on its `-` channel (stdin), then shuts the writing direction of the TCP socket and waits for the remote service to shutdown as well or for 10 seconds of inactivity whichever comes first. The `echo` service is meant to terminate the connection as soon as the other end has shut down its sending direction, so that command should not take any longer than the time it  takes to establish the connection, exchanging the data and shutting down.

With OpenBSD's `netcat` or its port to Linux which is the default one on recent versions of Debian and derivatives at least, an approximation would be `nc -Nw10 server 7` (that's different in that `nc`'s `-w` is both a connection timeout and an inactivity timeout)

To implement a TCP `echo` service on port 7777 for testing:

```
socat tcp-listen:7777,reuseaddr,fork exec:cat,nofork
```

(the `fork` to fork a process for each incoming connection, `nofork` to execute `cat` directly in that process with its stdin/stdout *being* the TCP socket, like when using `(x)inetd`).

Some timing on the loopback interface, with  `zsh`:

```
$ time echo test | socat -t10 - tcp:localhost:7777
test
echo test  0.00s user 0.00s system 54% cpu 0.001 total
socat -t10 - tcp:localhost:7777  0.00s user 0.01s system 55% cpu 0.009 total
```

Answer (score 0):

sending a ping to Redis and grep the PONG:

```
echo 'PING' | nc -w 1 server 6379 | grep PONG
```

Works as Ansible command.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best way to close gracefully the connection is to send the `Content-Length` header like following. Client (like `curl` will close the connection after receiving the data.

```bsh
DATA="Date: $(date)"; 
LENGTH=$(echo $DATA | wc -c);
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: ${LENGTH}\n\n${DATA}" | nc -l -p 8000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just check the `timeout` cmd while trying the `nc` command, like :

```
echo "test" | timeout 10 netcat server 7
```

This waits 10 sec before closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is quite old, and already has an accepted answer. However, that answer is very inelegant and doesn't really do what this question is asking for.

What you should be doing is passing the `-N` flag with your `netcat` command. The `-N` flag does the following:

> shutdown the network socket after EOF on the input. Some servers require
> this to finish their work.

So your command would look like this:

```
 echo 'test' | netcat -N server 7
```

Just for reference, passing the `-q 1` flag is just telling `netcat` to quit after 1 second. So that doesn't necessarily mean you'll get the output you want, or that whatever you are attempting will finish whatever it is you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using busybox netcat, the process of reading a reply and exiting can be achieved by using the `-w` flag:

```
nc server 7 -w1
```

*reads some response from server on port 7, waits one second and exits*

Unfortunately, the minimum wait time is 1 second. This may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score -1):

```
(echo 'test'; sleep 1) | netcat server 7
```

This keeps the input open for some time to delay `netcat` ending.