# Print and update variable inside find

Tags: bash, find, echo

I'd like to run a `find` command and process the files it returns, but also echo a count of the files processed as it goes, to give me a sense of its progress.

Right now, my command is (as an example):

```
COUNT=0\; find . -name '*.*' -exec echo "$COUNT: \c" \; -exec echo {} \;
```

But as a result, I don't get the count to echo (and I can't figure out how to increment it). I'd like it to give me something like:

```
0: ./FileOne.txt
1: ./FileTwo.txt
...
205: ./FileTwoHundredAndFive.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands executed by `find` are independent. Each `-exec` starts a new command. There's no way to transfer the current count from one command to the next, except by storing it somewhere (in a file) which would be very slow.

You can make find print something each time it sees a file, and pipe the output to a program that counts the input lines.

```
find … -print -exec 'the stuff you want to do' | nl
```

This will print counts after a delay due to buffering. See [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) on turning off buffering.

```
stdbuf -oL -eL find … -print -exec 'the stuff you want to do' | nl
```

Comment: Was afraid that was the case. I was hoping to avoid calling a script for such a dumb function, but if that's the only way, that's the only way. Thanks!