# Logs of the command running in the remote machine using ssh

Tags: ssh, logs, remote

I am sshing into a remote machine and running a command there using sudo. I am using tt for TTY connection. I want to get the output (the console logs) of the command that I am running in my local machine. How can I do that?

`ssh -i keyfile -tt user_name@$web_ip "sudo p.sh"`

Comment: I think this needs clarification. Is the output of the command that you are running on the local machine crucial to enable your command to run on the remote machine? Could you just copy the relevant file to the remote machine (using scp) before running your command over ssh?

Comment: I am running `ssh -i keyfile -tt user_name@$web_ip "sudo p.sh"` in my local machine. `p.sh` is getting executed on the remote. I want to direct the logs of p.sh in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -i keyfile user_name@$web_ip "sudo p.sh" > p.sh.local.log
```

I think this will do what you want, at least if p.sh is a pretty simple script (like `ls -al`).
(Note removing -tt)

For realtime logs:

```
ssh -t -i keyfile user_name@$web_ip "yes" > yes.local.log
```

Note: the yes command produces lots of output so this will make a large file fast. But it does update in realtime, in my test.

Comment: I can't remote tt since for running sudo it needs a TTY connection.

Comment: Also, if I move the logs in another file, I will have to scp that file to my local. Logs won't be in real time.

Comment: I haven't come across that sudo/TTY issue, but this question seems to cover it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password

Comment: Try adding one -t flag to get realtime logs. For comparison, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325236/view-script-output-over-ssh-in-real-time

Comment: I tried adding -t flag, it also gives error regarding TTY errors.

Comment: See comment above