# Grep output from USBPcap

Tags: grep, cygwin, hexdump

I hope cygwin questions fits here.

If I try:

```
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap4 -o - | hexdump -C
```

it gives me the expected result. But if I try to grep that result I get nothing:

```
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap4 -o - | hexdump -C  | grep "76 58"
```

I thing there is some kind of buffering hosing it up, becauce:

```
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap4 -o - | hexdump -C  | grep "76 58" > test.txt
```

leaves an empty text-file too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking further into my hunch, i found:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/209845

And my working command is:

```
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap4 -o - | stdbuf -oL -eL hexdump -C  | grep "76 58"
```