# Grepping strace output gets hard

Tags: grep, pipe, strace

I wrote the following code to determine which files a program writes to. I want to capture the filenames of course.

```
strace -f -t -e trace=file -p 8804 2>&1 | grep -oP "\"(.*)\".*O_WRONLY"
```

This outputs something like

```
/tmp/11111111.txt", O_WRONLY
```

The problem is I can't pipe the output of all this to any command

```
strace -f -t -e trace=file -p 8804 2>&1 | grep -oP "\"(.*)\".*O_WRONLY" | echo
# does not show anything
```

And also I can't save the output of all this for later use:

```
strace -f -t -e trace=file -p 8804 2>&1 | grep -oP "\"(.*)\".*O_WRONLY" > asd.out
# file is empty
```

Your help is appreciated. :)

Comment: `| echo` is wrong. `echo` echos the parameters, it does nothing with data given on stdin. Just remove it.

Comment: FWIW strace has a regex option, and in the strace man (see below) it tells you that you can pass the -o switch like `strace -e trace=%file -o "| grep NEEDLE" COMMAND` to search for string NEEDLE in the output from strace-ing an executable COMMAND.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the output to a file (with `strace -o asd.out`) and then grep it:

From strace manual:

```
-o filename Write  the  trace  output to the file filename rather than 
to stderr.  Use filename.pid if -ff is used. If the argument begins with
`|' or with `!' then the rest of the argument is treated as a command
and all output is piped to it. This is convenient for piping the
debugging output to a program without affecting the redirections of 
executed programs.
```

Comment: That's great, I tried and it works as it should. But if anyone knows the black magic behind the original problem, share me - out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem today.

FWIW you can use `| cat` instead of `| echo` in your example, `echo` apparently does nothing by default with no parameters.

On my box `strace ls 2>&1 | grep "execve" > asd.out` actually works OK...so you're doing it right.

My hunch is the problem is in the "attaching" like `strace -p xxx` because typically you have to hit `ctrl+c` to exit it and intermediate buffers in your command chain are **not flushed**.

So this works for me (I think it flushes on a new line because it detects it it outputting to "the screen"/terminal/tty):

`strace  ruby -e "sleep" 2>&1 |  grep execve`

but this doesn't

`strace  ruby -e "sleep" 2>&1 |  grep execve > my_output_file`

(I think because the final redirect is "not to a tty" so it uses a larger 4k internal buffer or something, or uses an internal buffer instead of buffering "by line" anymore).

But using a hint from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe), this works:

`strace  ruby -e "sleep" 2>&1 |  stdbuf -oL grep execve > me`

Pretty weird stuff.  In a disconcerting way.  And my theory is that with longer chains (ex: `grep | grep | grep` the size of the buffer grows linearly...4k each time...including for the one that writes it finally out to disk...)

Another thing that can help is insert an "output to screen" peeker in your chain, which is apparently `tee /dev/tty`:

`strace  ruby -e "sleep" 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | grep execve > my_output_file`

Then at least you'll see it on the screen even if it never makes it to the output file.

So anyway the take away from this is that strace logs to "normal" `stderr` (so if it's "running a process" eg. `strace ls` then the output from the process and strace will be *mixed*).  You can avoid the mixing by using the `-o output_file` parameter.

Also be careful you must redirect stdout first, then stderr, ex:

`progname >out.txt 2>&1`

order matters, it can't be the other way around.