# redirect shell output to file even when I kill the program

Tags: bash, signals, stdout

I am debugging a program that has a tendency to deadlock. On those occasions when it runs fine, `./program > log` or `./program | tee log` saves a copy of the output but if I do either of these, if the program deadlocks and I kill it with `^C` (SIGINT) then the log is always empty. I know that the program has written something to stdout because that happens before the part where anything can get stuck and indeed when I just run `./program` I see the output in the terminal.

I'd like a way to `tee` the output so that if I have to kill the program, the output so far is still saved in a log file. My shell is bash.

Comment: When you kill the program any output might be getting sent to STDERR instead of STDOUT, what happens when you do `./program > log 2>&1`

Comment: The lines that went to stderr in the first place are now in the log, but not the stdout ones.

Comment: What you are looking is to enable job control using `set -m` in your script and using `trap` on caught signal. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many (most?) programs, and practically all C or C++ programs, **'fully' buffer** stdout when it is a pipe or disk file, or in general not `isattty()`, and any output still in the buffer and not flushed to the OS when you kill it is lost. Programs normally do NOT do this buffering for stderr, which is why that works.

In general use `stdbuf -oL program ...` or possibly `-o0`. Some programs have their own private options e.g. GNU sed has `-u/--unbuffered`.

Alternatively use something that runs the program under a pty and thus turns off buffering, including `script`, `screen`, `expect` or its simplified form `unbuffer`, or `ssh -t`.

For more details and options see [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)