# Grep slow to exit after finding match?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to write a bash script that polls btmon for device connections. I've got a working solution, but it's absurdly slow, and it seems like the issue is grep being very slow to exit after finding a match (around 25 seconds). What can I do to either speed `grep` up or avoid using it altogether?

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
while :
  do
    until btmon | grep -m 1 '@ Device Connected'
      do :
    done
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    echo on 0 | cec-client RPI -s -d 1
    sleep 5
    echo as | cec-client RPI -s -d 1
    until btmon | grep -m 1 '@ Device Disconnected'
      do :
    done
    let COUNTER=COUNTER-1
    if [ $COUNTER -eq 0 ];
      then echo standby 0 | cec-client RPI -s -d 1;
    fi
done
```

edit: To clarify, `btmon` and is a bluetooth monitoring tool that's part of the Bluez suite, and cec-client is a utility that's packaged with libCEC for issuing commands across the HDMI-CEC serial bus (amongst other things).

Comment: How much "stuff" does `btmon` output? are you sure it's not just a matter of buffering?

Comment: @steeldriver Seconded. Have you tried [disabling buffering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/3645) in the pipe?

Comment: btmon outputs about 250 characters per second.

Comment: @l0b0 I tried disabling buffering with the unbuffer command, but that seems to prevent grep from exiting at all? I also tried forcing grep to --line-buffer mode, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: It could be that `btmon` implements buffering itself, in which case you're out of luck.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Most shells (the Bourne shell, (t)csh, as well as yash and some versions of AT&T ksh under some conditions being the notable exceptions) wait for both `cmd1` and `cmd2`.

In `bash`, you'll notice that

```
sleep 1 | uname
```

returns after one second.

In:

```
btmon | grep -m 1 '@ Device Disconnected'
```

`grep` will exit as soon as it has found one occurrence of the pattern, but `bash` will still wait for `btmon`.

`btmon` will typically die of a SIGPIPE the next time it writes to the pipe after `grep` has returned, but if it never writes anything again, it would never receive that signal.

You could replace `#! /bin/bash` with `#! /bin/ksh93 -` as that's a shell compatible with `bash` and one that only waits for the last component of a pipeline. Then in

```
btmon | grep -m 1 '@ Device Disconnected'
```

after `grep` returns, `btmon` would be left running in background and the shell would carry on with the rest of the script.

If you wanted to kill `btmon` as soon as `grep` returns, POSIXly, you could do something like:

```
sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec btmon' | (
   read pid
   grep -m1 '@ Device Disconnected' || exit
   kill "$pid" 2> /dev/null
   true)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this is behaving the way it does. It didn't occur to me that bash might be waiting for btmon to exit. Swapping to ksh93 works beautifully!