# Silently kill subshell?

Tags: kill, output, subshell

I want to implement something like this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722850/773263) but for a sub-shell. Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying:

```
(subshell=$BASHPID
  (kill $subshell & wait $subshell 2>/dev/null) &
sleep 600)

echo subshell done
```

How can I make it so only `subshell done` returns instead of:

```
./test.sh: line 4:  5439 Terminated              ( subshell=$BASHPID; ( kill $subshell && wait $subshell 2> /dev/null ) & sleep 600 )
subshell done
```

*Edit: I may be wrong on the terminology here, by subshell I mean the process within the first set of brackets.*

**Update:**

I want to post the snippet from the actual program for context, above is a simplification:

```
# If subshell below if killed or returns error connected variable won't be set
(if [ -n "$2" ];then

      # code to setup wpa configurations here

      # If wifi key is wrong kill subshell
      subshell=$BASHPID
      (sudo stdbuf -o0 wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i$wifi -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 2>&1 \
        | grep -m 1 "pre-shared key may be incorrect" \
        && kill -s PIPE "$subshell") &

      # More code which does the setup necessary for wifi

) && connected=true

# later json will be returned based on if connected is set
```

Comment: In perspective, you’re killing the parent shell.

Comment: @JeffSchaller why does the `echo` still run if the parent script is killed?

Comment: You're not killing the "grandfather" where the `echo` is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note:

- `wait $subshell` won't work as `$subshell` is not a child of the process you're running `wait` in. Anyway, you'd not waiting for the process doing the `wait` so it doesn't matter much.
- `kill $subshell` is going to kill the subshell but not `sleep` if the subshell had managed to start it by the time `kill` was run. You could however run `sleep` in the same process with `exec`
- you can use SIGPIPE instead of SIGTERM to avoid the message
- leaving a variable unquoted in list contexts has a very special meaning in `bash`.

So having said all that, you can do:

```
(
  subshell=$BASHPID
  kill -s PIPE "$subshell" &
  sleep 600
)
echo subshell done
```

(replace `sleep 60` with `exec sleep 60` if you want the `kill` to kill `sleep` and not just the subshell, which in this case might not even have time to run `sleep` by the time you kill it).

In any case, I'm not sure what you want to achieve with that.

```
sleep 600 &
```

would be a more reliable way to start `sleep` in background if that's what you wanted to do (or `(sleep 600 &)` if you wanted to hide that `sleep` process from the main shell)

Now with your actual

```
sudo stdbuf -o0 wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i"$wifi" -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

command, note that `sudo` does spawn a child process to run the command (if only because it may need to log its status or perform some PAM session tasks afterwards). `stdbuf` will however execute `wpa_supplicant` in the same process, so in the end you'll have three processes (in addition to the rest of the script) in `wpa_supplicant`'s ancestry:

1. the subshell
2. sudo as a child of 1
3. wpa_supplicant (which was earlier running stdbuf) as a child of 2

If you kill 1, that doesn't automatically kills 2. If you kill 2 however, unless it's with a signal like SIGKILL that can't be intercepted, that will kill 3 as `sudo` happens to forward the signals it receives to the command it runs.

In any case, that's not the subshell you'd want to kill here, it's 3 or at least 2.

Now, if it's running as `root` and the rest of the script is not, you won't be able to kill it so easily.

You'd need the `kill` to be done as `root`, so you'd need:

```
sudo WIFI="$wifi" bash -c '
  (echo "$BASHPID" &&
   exec stdbuf -o0 wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i"$WIFI" -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 2>&1
  ) | {
    read pid &&
      grep -m1 "pre-shared key may be incorrect" &&
      kill -s PIPE "$pid"
  }'
```

That way, `wpa_supplicant` will be running in the same `$BASHPID` process as the subshell as we're making of that with `exec`.

We get the pid through the pipe and run `kill` as root.

Note that if you're ready to wait a little longer,

```
sudo stdbuf -o0 wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i"$wifi" -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 2>&1 |
  grep -m1 "pre-shared key may be incorrect"
```

Would have `wpa_supplicant` killed automatically with a SIGPIPE (by the system, so no permission issue) the *next time* it writes something to that pipe after `grep` is gone.

Some shell implementations would not wait for `sudo` after `grep` has returned (leaving it running in background until it gets SIGPIPEd), and with `bash`, you can also do that using the `grep ... <(sudo ...)` syntax, where `bash` doesn't wait for `sudo` either after `grep` has returned.

More at [Grep slow to exit after finding match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366797)

Comment: thanks processing this now, the `sleep` probably seems weird. In my actual code I have a process being grepped for errors, if found I run `&& kill`. The `sleep` represents a longer code block I have that starts running but should be stopped in the case of particular errors. The `echo` is the success or failure json response (which I don't want to contain the process terminated text).

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, if you wanted to kill a process as soon as it outputs something, see for instance [Grep slow to exit after finding match?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/366806)

Comment: I think what you posted is the solution I need. I'm a bit confused about how you mentioned `exec` are you saying `sleep` will still be running in the background with what you posted?

Comment: I updated my question with an actual snippet, the `sudo stdbuf -o0 wpa_supplicant ...` would be the `sleep`. So I definitely want that process to end when I run `kill -s PIPE "$subshell"`.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, see edit.

Comment: Great answer, glad I posted the original as the `sudo` issue is a real gotcha in this situation. It will be funny adding `/bin/bash` to my sudoers file. I might have to look at running the whole script as `sudo` instead. Cheers!

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, yes it would make more sense to add the script to sudoers here. See also zsh instead of bash to interpret your script, which has support for changing uids so could relinquish super user privileges for parts of the script that don't need them. It feels like there should be a cleaner solution by configuring wpa_supplicant to do what you want. If you ask a question about what you're trying to do in the end, you may get answers with better way to address the problem.

Comment: Good point, it's probably out of scope here so I made a new post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407168/wpa-supplicant-end-process-if-wrong-password-detected

Answer (score 2):

Subshell refers to a shell command that is a child of some shell, such as child of the `bash -i` interactive login shell that offers you a `$` prompt. You don't *have* to run your command in a subshell - you could choose to run it as an independent process. It sounds like this may be appropriate because you don't want its stdout / stderr messing up the appearance of your progress bar, and because you don't want the parent shell to report on or even notice the death of its child.

There are standard tools for accomplishing that, such as [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/) and nohup. (See also [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize) [pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon).) You may be best off with [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup). Here is an example of using it to run a trivial program, which does *not* create nohup.out:

```
$ nohup true 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

Have your program, or a wrapper script for your program, record its PID in /tmp/my.pid -- bash makes that available as the `$$` variable. Then the monitoring process with the progress bar can

```
$ kill `cat /tmp/my.pid`
```

when it no longer needs that program to do any more processing. Alternatively, you might prefer to give your program name to `killall`.

Comment: I don't think your idea of a subshell matches the meaning it's used in e.g. the Bash manual: "Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment,  ... Builtin commands that are invoked as part of a pipeline are also executed in a subshell environment. Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell’s execution environment."

Comment: When you type (cmd) or (foo|bar), your bash forks off a 2nd bash (a subshell process) that runs the command or pipeline. The benefit of the fork is you can change env variables for the subshell without disturbing their setting in the parent shell. There is a parent-child relationship between them that is usually helpful but seemed to be causing some small grief for the OP, which is why I suggested accomplishing the required cmd processing under nohup instead of under the parent shell. He was a bit vague on details of what that processing entails, so I went for a general, silent solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for this

```
#!/bin/bash
(subshell=$BASHPID
  (kill $subshell & wait $subshell 2>/dev/null) &
sleep 600) &
wait $! 2>/dev/null

echo subshell done
```

here the subshell is put in background, then parent shell waits but with
wait output sent to /dev/null. This catches the `Terminated` message.

Note, if you change wait to capture output to file e.g. `wait $! 2>wait_output` then you will see

```
 ./foo.sh: line 5:  1939 Terminated              ( subshell=$BASHPID; ( kill $subshell & wait $subshell 2> /dev/null ) & sleep 600 )
```

showing that `Terminated` is from parent shell.

A small check to see that it works if there is some activity before kill is

```
#!/bin/bash
(subshell=$BASHPID
 (sleep 1; kill $subshell & wait $subshell 2>/dev/null) &
sleep 600) & wait 2>wait_output

echo subshell done
```

This example will pause for a second before printing `subshell done`. This example also shows how to background and wait all on the same line e.g. `& wait 2>wait_output`. I am not sure if that has any advantage/disadvantage over the example with `wait $!`.

The key thing to note here is that the `Terminated` messages comes from the top-level parent shell job control. That is what sees the subshell terminate and generates the message. So that is where you want to catch the output. Redirecting the `wait` command output does this.