# Why a combination of tail+grep+cut doesn't work?

Tags: text-processing, grep, scripting, tail, cut

I wanted to grep some logs, while tailing them, and print only a part of each line, since the lines are too long.

I can't figure out why the combination I use doesn't work; the procedure follows:

```
echo 'Jun 29 16:27:00 someip rails[pid]: Killed a transaction
Jun 29 16:28:00 someip rails[pid]: Killed a transaction' > /tmp/test

# Shows the lines
tail -f /tmp/test | grep Killed

# Shows the lines
grep Killed /tmp/test | cut -c -43

# Shows the lines
cat /tmp/test | grep Killed | cut -c -43

# Doesn't show them
tail -f /tmp/test | grep Killed | cut -c -43
```

Why doesn't the last combination work?

Comment: probably because of buffering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858912/piping-tail-output-though-grep-twice

Comment: that's correct. if you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Similar: [Can't redirect cut output](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/226625)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments , the issue is due to buffering. What you can do is to run command with `stdbuf` as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/85039).

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tail -f /tmp/test | grep Killed | cut -c -43
```

On side note, you probably could get rid of `grep` and `cut` pipeline, and use :

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tail -f /tmp/test | awk '/Killed/{print substr($0,length($0)-43)}'
```