# Grep cURL output

Tags: grep, curl, output

When I run

```
curl https://example.com -o example.html 2>&1 | grep -P "\d.*\d"
```

I get this output (in red):

```
100  1270  100  1270    0     0    318      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 0:00:00   318
```

What I want is just to show the last line of cURL's progress bar *as it updates* (I actually only want certain columns to be shown, but showing the whole line is fine)

Wanted output (at time t = 1 sec):

```
user@comp:~/Desktop/$ curl https://example.com -o example.html 2>&1 | grep -P "\d.*\d"
25  1270  25  318    0     0    318      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 0:00:03   318
```

Wanted output (at time t = 2 sec):

```
user@comp:~/Desktop/$ curl https://example.com -o example.html 2>&1 | grep -P "\d.*\d"
50  1270  50  636    0     0    318      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 0:00:02   318
```

Wanted output (at time t = 3 sec):

```
user@comp:~/Desktop/$ curl https://example.com -o example.html 2>&1 | grep -P "\d.*\d"
75  1270  75  954    0     0    318      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 0:00:01   318
```

Wanted output (at time t = 4 sec):

```
user@comp:~/Desktop/$ curl https://example.com -o example.html 2>&1 | grep -P "\d.*\d"
100  1270  100 1270    0     0    317      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 0:00:00   0
```

I've tried using watch with cURL and grep, but it still doesn't work (no output)

```
watch --no-title --interval 1 "curl http://example.com -o test2.html" | grep -P '\d.*\d'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly `| grep` the output of curl progress because of pipe buffering. Some great insights on this issue is available in this previous question: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

As for a solution, using `stdbuf` and `tr`:

```
curl https://example.com -o example.html 2>&1 | stdbuf -oL tr -s '\r' '\n' | while read i; do echo -en "\r$i  "; done
```

With:

- `stdbuf -oL`: stdout of `tr` will be line buffered for proper processing by the `while` loop
- `tr -s '\r' '\n'`: replace carriage return with newline from `curl` output
- `while read i; do echo -en "\r$i  "; done`: simple `bash` solution for a progress line