# Insert Newlines into serial stream before writing to text file

Tags: sed, serial-port, newlines

I have an RFID reader which sends the Unique ID of the RFID tag to the serial port of my linux (raspberry pi) box every time it gets a successful read. The problem is that it is sending it without any newline characters. 
Here's an example of the output:

```
root@scalepi:~/scale# ./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#
```

I'd like to write each entry to a text file with a new line, like this:

```
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#
```

As you can see each entry begins with $ and ends with #

I have tried just piping the outout to sed using this line to add a new line after the #, but I get zero output, because I think sed is looking for a new line before it processes the data:

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | sed 's/#/#\r\n/g'
```

If I redirect the output to a file, and then cat the file, piped through that same sed command, I get what I expect, but I need to be able to write the data to a file in this format, so I can read it in realtime.

```
root@scalepi:~/scale# ./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 > /tmp/test2.txt
^C
root@scalepi:~/scale# cat /tmp/test2.txt | sed 's/#/#\r\n/g'
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E#
root@scalepi:~/scale#
```

If anyone has any suggestions for me, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT - UPDATED

After trying the "tr" solution below, I was able to get real time output, but if I try to redirect via  pipe, or via stdout/stderr redirection, I get buffered results of 50-60 lines at a time instead of getting a line by line result.

The following command will give me real time output as it comes in on the serial port:

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | tr '#' '\n'
```

The following command will give me output in chunks of 50 or 60 lines at a time (not real time):

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | tr '#' '\n' | sed -u 's/$/#\r/g'
```

The following command will give me output to a text file in chunks of 50 or 60 lines at a time (not real time):

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | tr '#' '\n'  > /tmp/test1.txt
```

FWIW, I get the same results using cat to read the serial port, instead of "grabserial".

The following command gives me realtime results:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB4 | tr '#' '\n'
```

But when I try to redirect output via either pipe or stdout redirection, I get buffered chunks of data in the text file:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB4 | tr '#' '\n' > /tmp/test4.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate (or transliterate) the `#` characters into newlines with

```
 tr '#' '\n'
```

so

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | tr '#' '\n'
```

should give you

```
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
$A0112OKD9990001200005643E
            ︙
```

in real time. 
If you *need* the pound signs and/or the carriage returns,
you can pipe the above into

```
        … sed 's/$/#\r/'
```

(using the fact that `sed` (and regular expressions in general)
use `$` to represent the end of a line.

## Gotcha

You may have a problem
that `tr` buffers its output when that output is going to a pipe or a file. 
Perhaps the best way to handle this is to follow [αғsнιη’s advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393939/80216#393942)
to turn off buffering with `stdbuf`; e.g.,

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | stdbuf -oL tr '#' '\n' | sed 's/$/#\r/' > RFIDs.txt
```

In case it’s unclear,
the option to `stdbuf` is lower-case `o` (oh) and upper-case `L` (ell),
which says that the standard output should be line-buffered.

#### Bottom line (TL;DR) #1:

So you should be able to use

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | stdbuf -oL tr '#' '\n' > RFIDs.txt
```

to get the entries without the `#` at the end, or

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | stdbuf -oL tr '#' '\n' | sed 's/$/#/' > RFIDs.txt
```

to get the entries with the `#` at the end, but without the `\r`, or

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | stdbuf -oL tr '#' '\n' | sed 's/$/#\r/' > RFIDs.txt
```

to get the entries with the `#` ***and*** the `\r` at the end.

#### Bottom line (TL;DR) #2:

You haven’t said how you’re terminating the command. 
If you’re typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
that *might* be causing a problem<sup>1</sup>. 
If so, try:

- putting one of the above command lines into the background with `&`,
  and then
- when you’re ready to quit,
  do a `ps` and get the PID of the `grabserial` process, and
- kill it with the `kill` command.

#### Bottom line (TL;DR) #3:

You say you need to be able to read the data in real time,
without going into specifics. 
If you have some program / script that is capable of reading from stdin,
try

```
./grabserial -d "/dev/ttyUSB4" -b 9600 | stdbuf -oL tr '#' '\n' | sed 's/$/#\r/' | tee RFIDs.txt | your_program
```

This should write the data to the output file
while simultaneously piping it to your program.

#### Bottom line (TL;DR) #4:

If, in fact, `cat` works as well as `grabserial`, then you don’t actually need either one;
things like

```
stdbuf -oL tr '#' '\n' < /dev/ttyUSB4 | sed 's/$/#\r/' > RFIDs.txt
```

should work just as well.
____________
<sup>1</sup> Based on your update, this is probably not your problem,
but I’m leaving this here in case it helps somebody else.

---

Note that `tr` basically operates on a one-to-one basis. 
(There are some options to do some slightly fancier stuff.) 
So, for example,

```
tr 'abc…' 'ABC…'
```

will replace `a` with `A`, `b` with `B`, `c` with `C`, etc. 
So you *can’t* do something like

```
tr '#' '#\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks. that at least got me closer, but I still can't get it to a text file for some reason. No matter how I redirect the output, either to a file, or to another pipe, I just get no output.

Comment: I updated the main question with the results of your suggestion.

Comment: I added a whole bunch of stuff to my answer in response to your comment.  Now that I have a clearer idea of your problem (from your update to the question), a lot of it is irrelevant, redundant, and / or superfluous, but I’m leaving it there as it may help others.

Comment: Thanks for your help. FWIW, in your Bottom Line #1 example, I had to use the "-u" flag for sed, to get it to send to a text file without buffering (if I wanted the # at the end of the line).

Answer (score 1):

Because `sed` normally buffering its output until a buffer size fills up ( Probably 4K bytes), you could use `-u` as GNU specific option to unbuffer the output.

Please see [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/72456) and related [answer for `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53445/72456).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion here. I felt like the bulk of the answer came from G-Man, so I awarded him the "solve", but yours was helpful, and useful in this scenario.