# unix nohup logs are filled with 0 bytes

Tags: logs, nohup

I am running the monitoring scripts in the background. They are supposed to   all day (24x7).

In the script, based on the monitor output I have a function to start a process using `nohup`, redirecting the output to the log file /`home/nohub_logs/logfile.txt`.

The script  works fine for few hours but after these few hours the log file is still zero bytes length. Sometimes if I kill the monitoring script and restart the script I get some output.

```
nohup startprocessscript.sh >> /home/nohuplog &
```

Logs are getting generated after some time. For example, if the script is running for the first 24 hours, then after 24 hours the logs are not getting created. If we restart the script the logs are created.

I am not sure why sometime the `nohup` log files are not getting any generated data. Can anyone help me, please.

Comment: It seems that some logs are created and updated fine, while some are not. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: nohup   startprocessscript.sh >> /home/nohuplog & this is the command I am using  logs are getting generated after some times  say script is working for first 24 hours .. after 24 hours the  logs are not getting created. if we restart the script the logs are created.

Comment: You wrote "filled with 0 bytes", but you really mean that the output files stays empty (at size zero)?

Answer (score 2):

A common reason for this issue is output buffering.

Your script output might be flushed to the log file only after enough data has been written.

Possible workarounds are `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` see [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/25378#25378)