# Using jq within pipe chain produces no output

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, jq

The issue of `jq` needing an explicit filter when the output is redirected is discussed all over the web. But I'm unable to redirect output if `jq` is part of a pipe chain, even when an explicit filter is in use.

Consider:

```
touch in.txt
tail -f in.txt | jq '.f1'
# in a different terminal:
echo '{"f1":1,"f2":2}' >> in.txt
echo '{"f1":3,"f2":2}' >> in.txt
```

As expected, the output in the original terminal from the `jq` command is:

```
1
3
```

But if I add any sort of redirection or piping to the end of the `jq` command, the output goes silent:

```
rm in.txt
touch in.txt
tail -f in.txt | jq '.f1' | tee out.txt
# in a different terminal:
echo '{"f1":1,"f2":2}' >> in.txt
echo '{"f1":3,"f2":2}' >> in.txt
```

No output appears in the first terminal and out.txt is empty.

I've tried hundreds of variations but it's an elusive issue. The only [workaround I've found](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/mosquitto-sub-piping-not-working-with-ttn-v2/4858/2), as discovered through `mosquitto_sub` and The Things Network (which was where I also discovered the issue), is to wrap the tail **and** jq functions in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f $1 | while IFS='' read line; do
echo $line | jq '.f1'
done
```

Then:

```
./tail_and_jq.sh | tee out.txt
# in a different terminal:
echo '{"f1":1,"f2":2}' >> in.txt
echo '{"f1":3,"f2":2}' >> in.txt
```

And sure enough, the output appears:

```
1
3
```

This is with the latest `jq` installed via Homebrew:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ jq --version
jq-1.5
$ brew install jq
Warning: jq 1.5_3 is already installed and up-to-date
```

Is this a (largely undocumented) bug in `jq` or with my understanding of pipe chains?

Comment: FWIW you have a fairly (well, slightly) strange setup here, using `tail -f` to provide continuous input to a program and `tee` to process the output. If you were still in need of an answer, I would have suggested simplifying the chain to `<in.json jq '.f1' >out.json` so that you could narrow down what's causing it.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) - *What is buffering? Or, why does my command line produce no output: `tail -f logfile | grep 'foo bar' | awk ...`*

Comment: All great advice for future efforts, thank you. FWIW, the `tail` bit came about from efforts to break the pipe down (run the first command, tee and redirect to file, tail that, pipe to next command, redirect to file, etc) and run it continuously in sections. The `<` is a good tool to keep in mind though.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The output from `jq` is buffered when its standard output is not a terminal.

To request that `jq` flushes its output buffer after every object, use its `--unbuffered` option, e.g.

```
tail -f in.txt | jq --unbuffered '.f1' | tee out.txt
```

From the `jq` manual:

> `--unbuffered`
>
> Flush the output after each JSON object is printed (useful if you're piping a slow data source into `jq` and piping `jq`'s output elsewhere).

Comment: Further, the way I would debug this, in order to figure out that output buffering was the issue, assuming I wouldn't simply guess that, would be to run the 'jq' portion under 'ltrace' and/or 'strace'. It would be obvious that it's calling C stdio output functions, but not calling the write(2) syscall.

Comment: @AnotherSmellyGeek Possibly, or the equivalent tracing utility on our Unices (note that the OP is using Homebrew, which means they're on macOS, and I'm on OpenBSD, neither of which has these Linux tools). Another possibility is to just know that output buffering may happen under certain circumstances :-)

Comment: Brilliant. And really appreciate all the advice on debugging this in the future. Buffering was one of my first doubts, but the different behaviour for piping was flummoxing my debugging efforts.

Answer (score 10):

What you're seeing here is the C stdio buffering in action. It will store output on a buffer until it reaches a certain limit (might be 512 bytes, or 4KB or larger) and then send that all at once.

This buffering gets disabled automatically if stdout is connected to a terminal, but when it's connected to a pipe (such as in your case), it will enable this buffering behavior.

The usual way to disable/control buffering is using the `setvbuf()` function (see [this answer](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) for more details), but that would need to be done in the source code of `jq` itself, so maybe not something practical for you...

There's a workaround... (A hack, one might say.) There's a program called "unbuffer", that's distributed with "expect" that can create a pseudo-terminal and connect that to a program. So, even though `jq` will still be writing to a pipe, it will think it's writing to a terminal, and the buffering effect will be disabled.

Install the "expect" package, which should come with "unbuffer", if you don't already have it... For instance, on Debian (or Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install expect
```

Then you can use this command:

```
$ tail -f in.txt | unbuffer -p jq '.f1' | tee out.txt
```

See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375/281844) for some more details on "unbuffer", and you can find a [man page here too](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html).

Comment: I like that you've explained why the observed behavior occurs, but as Kusalananda pointed out, `jq` natively implements unbuffered output so there's no need for the workaround.

Comment: Ah very nice! I started looking in the `jq` man page but got bored after a while and went to do other stuff... Good to know there's something like that! :-)

Comment: Protip, GNU coreutils come with `stdbuf -o0` which will inject code via LD_PRELOAD and do the `setvbuf()` magic call for you. Whether it works on macOS, I'm not sure.

Comment: While `expect` is pre-installed on macos, `unbuffer` is not. However it is part of the Homebrew package, so on macos, `brew install expect` will do.

Comment: Beware `unbuffer -p` is severely broken, see [Why does unbuffer -p mangle its input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/760143) (includes a work around)