# problem with piplining using jq

Tags: pipe, jq

The **exact** question was asked here:

[Using jq within pipe chain produces no output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435413/using-jq-within-pipe-chain-produces-no-output)

but the answser provided there did not solve my problem.  Also, I read the following:

- [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/25375#25375)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809196/how-do-i-keep-colors-when-piping-jq-output-to-less

None of these solved my problem.  OK, the above info is to let you know that I have done my homework, and please do not downvote or close this question, before you read on :-)

I use the following command to **pretty print** a json file:

```
cat a-json-file.json |jq|less
```

But the screen shows an `(END)` at the bottom, nothing is displayed.  I then googled the problem, found the above info, tried:

```
cat a-json-file.json |jq --unbuffered|less
```

nothing happens. Then I installed `expect`, try:

```
cat a-json-file.json |unbuffer jq|less
```

It does not work either, `jq` simply output its command line usage info!

Finally, I got the problem solved by this:

```
jq "." a-json-file.json |less
```

Now, the question is, WHY pipe chain does not work with jq, and what's the difference between the above non-working and working commands?

My system info: `Debian 10 buster`, `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe`.

Comment: Did you also try `cat a-json-file.json |jq '.'|less`? This seems to have been a known issue with jq 1.5 - see for example [Redirecting or piping output has different behaviour #1028](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1028) and the Bug fixes section of the [jq 1.6 release notes](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.6)

Answer (score 3):

The comment by @steeldriver solved the problem:

> Did you also try `cat a-json-file.json |jq '.'|less`? This seems to have been a known issue with jq 1.5 - see for example [Redirecting or piping output has different behaviour #1028](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1028) and the Bug fixes section of the [jq 1.6 release notes](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.6)