# AWK in the middle of a pipe returns no output

Tags: awk, pipe

I want to process all changed logfiles from apache and made a simple oneliner:

```
inotifywait --format="%w%f" -rm /var/log/apache2/ | gawk '{ print }'
```

This is exactly my start. But if I pipe that output further, I get no output:

```
inotifywait --format="%w%f" -rm /var/log/apache2/ | gawk '{ print }' | wc -l
```

Anyway, if I use 'ls', 'tail' (what I really want), there is never output
(in another console, running the first statement, I know, there are changes).
I tried with adding stdbuf, fflush(), nothing works. I dont understand the problem!
I want to keep this onliner into a script, which I can use as a string point. Otherwise, I could (but dont wish to) use xargs.
Any help or tips would be fine!

Comment: So it still doesn't work with the correct quoting in place?

Comment: turn off buffering (or at least make it line-based) for *all* the things. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: Thanks for all hints!
It just needs to much time to solve this problem - I am working for hours on that. After applying all recommendations to disable buffering (some of them I tried also bevore) and none worked, I am going back to use xargs. It is even an unsupported debian (squeeze - a new hardware is on my table sinde two years ...).
Thanks anyone.

Comment: I answered the question, but it's really not clear what your desired result is. The `awk` command here does nothing at all. `wc` and `tail` don't print anything until all data is read. `ls` doesn't read stdin at all.

Comment: you may have a different problem to me, however I found I can get non-buffered output from `awk` with `fflush()` -- As:  `gawk -e '{ prnt ; fflush(); }'`.  It must have the empty parentheses"()".  Alternatively try ` ... | mawk` as: `mawk -Winteractive -e '{ print $0; }' | ...`

Answer (score 2):

The reason you do not get output is because `wc -l` is consuming all of the output. You can use `tee` in combination with process substitution to get `awk` to output to the console as well as read by `wc`:

```
inotifywait --format="%w%f" -rm /var/log/apache2/ | gawk '{ print }' | tee >(wc -l)
```

This is still slightly problematic as `inotifywait` is a command that never exits, but `wc -l` does not print output until it has read all the data, in this case when the pipe closes. You can do your counting directly in `awk`:

```
inotifywait --format="%w%f" -rm /var/log/apache2/ | gawk 'BEGIN { total=0 } { print; total++; print total } END { print "final total: " total }'
```

Comment: or use builtin `awk '{print;print NR} END{print "final",NR}`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yeah, that's much better.