# sed not working correctly when piped

Tags: shell-script, sed, pipe

For some reason, I will not have live output when piping the command output of e.g. SSH to sed:

```
ssh someuser@somehost 2>&1 | sed -e "s/\[32//g" | tee logging
```

I suspected that the output dit not have newlines, but when i remove the sed command and run:

```
wc -l logging
```

It returns 6, which is the correct number of returns. Does anybody have an idea what i am missing here?

[EDIT]
I completely forgot to mention the following: running

```
ssh someuser@somehost 2>&1 | sed -e "s/\[32//g"
```

returns all values no problem, however, as soon as i add tee into the mix, i won't get outputs until I hit ^C... Not even standard output redirection works (ssh someuser@somehost 2>&1 | sed -e "s/[32//g" > file). Just ssh with tee also works fine.

Comment: Possibly related: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Comment: It's the same old buffering problem -- on linux, you can work it around by replacing the `sed ...` with `stdbuf -oL sed ...`. Though notice that you won't have echoing and prompting in the interactive `ssh` if you use `sed` at all (with or without `tee`).  If your case, I wonder why you aren't simply using `script(1)`.

Comment: or if `sed` is GNU `sed`, use `sed -u`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stream editor, sed, buffers, disable with '-u' or '--unbuffered'.

```
tail -f some/log_file | sed -u 's/foo//g' | grep bar
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run `ssh user@somehost` without an explicit command, you're requesting ssh to start an interactive shell on the remote machine.

An interactive shell (such as bash) typically wants to have a *terminal* available, since it will use terminal commands to implement improved experience when editing the command line and browsing the history. (Terminal commands allow full-screen control.)

But ssh will only allocate a terminal by default (also called a *pseudo-terminal*) if its standard output is connected to a terminal.

If you simply run `ssh user@somehost` from a terminal program (such as gnome-terminal, rxvt, xterm, etc.), then its standard output will be a terminal, so ssh will create a pseudo-terminal and the remote interactive shell will behave nicely.

If you pipe ssh through something (anything), like `ssh user@somehost | cat`, then its standard output will be a pipe (and not the terminal), so ssh will not create a terminal and that might make the remote interactive shell misbehave.

A possible solution is to force ssh to create a pseudo-terminal, by passing it the `-t` option, like `ssh -t user@somehost | cat`, which *might* help. (Also, you might need a double option `-tt` to force allocation of the pseudo-terminal.)

Another possibility, if you're running ssh mainly because you're interested on a specific command, is to run the specific command from the ssh command line, such as `ssh user@somehost mycommand | cat`. If you run a specific command, an interactive shell does not get involved, in which case having a terminal available is likely not going to cause any issues.

Comment: Nope, sadly the -t option does not help...

Answer (score 0):

I would try the same command with the following addition:

```bsh
ssh someuser@somehost 2>&1 | sed -e "s/\[32//g" | tee --output-error=warn logging
```

With that, you should be able to see if there is an error in writing to stdout. Let me know if that helps.

You could install expect, then try:

```bsh
unbuffer ssh someuser@somehost 2>&1 | sed -e "s/\[32//g" | tee logging
```

Comment: Nope, no errors...