# Flush the pipe/printf buffers externally for already running process with known PID

Tags: shell, pipe, file-descriptors, buffer

I am writing a data logging app, all programs are started like:

```
./program > out.bin
```

The data collector periodically pools the stdout output files and reads the data.

The issue is that the IO streams are buffered and if some program outputs data in like 1 byte per second, it takes a lot of time (up too 4k seconds with default 4kB buffer size) before the data are actually flushed out.

My question is how to force the stdout/pipe/printf buffer to flush externally, i.e. call externally something like `fflush(stdout)`.

I have read various sites like [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/25378) , but I can not disable the buffers as it have huge IO performace impact (measured).

I am looking for high performace solution for production and these following conditions are always met:

- the program (data producer) PID is always known
- the output is always a file with known path
- the data logging process has full root access

Answer (score 5):

```
gdb -p PID -batch -ex 'p fflush(stdout)'
```

As with any debugging and hacking, YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have access to the source of the running programs?

Forcing a flush of an arbitrary executable is, while not theoretically impossible, very difficult. You would need to find the `fflush` function in the code and the `stdout` argument, then interrupt the execution of the program, arrange for the call to `fflush`, then continue execution. If the program is using a shared library, that at least makes the first part easier, finding `fflush` and `stdout`, but you still need to simulate the call. Also, for an unknown binary, you can't know whether it used stdio or whether it implements its own buffering mechanism. Knowing the path of the output file will not help you.

You can try to use `gdb`, then use the `attach` command to attach to the process. Maybe `gdb` can call the `fflush` function.

If you have the source to the program, implement a signal handler that flushes the buffer and just send the signal when you want the buffer flushed.

You can try a pipe, maybe the programs don't buffer if the output is a pipe. Change it to

```
./program | your_program > out.bin
```

Your program can accept the input, buffer it and flush the buffer when it receives a signal. It would still add CPU overhead, but not disk overhead.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not modify the data producer programs in any way.

Comment: I added an idea about `gdb`. But I think `stdout` is a macro and not available as a symbol at runtime.

Comment: Does in use dynamic libraries? May be you can change the libraries, to do the same.

Comment: I added an idea about using a pipe. @ctrl-alt-delor's idea with changes in a dynamic library might also work.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I presume most of them yes, the typical programs are java, php cli, ... I will definitely test.

Comment: @RalfFriedl But then there will be a pipe buffer, won't? The CPU overhead should be ok if I can keep the buffering and enforce pipe flush when needed.

Comment: My current Linux C library, glibc-2.29, sets stdio to unbuffered if it is a pipe. There is a buffer in the kernel, but it is never written to disk, and the content is passed on immediately.

Comment: @RalfFriedl "glibc ... sets stdio to unbuffered if it is a pipe" No it doesn't. `glibc` only sets *stdout* to *line* buffered if it's a tty. Otherwise it's FULLY buffered by default. I think that's even required by the standard.