# How to print streaming JSON to file after processing with JQ and SED

Tags: sed, curl, json, jq, streaming

I am using the following code to download streaming financial data

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX..." "https://...=EUR_USD" | jq --raw-output '[.time, .bids[0].price, .asks[0].price] | @csv'
```

which is successfully streaming in the terminal thus

```
"2020-05-05T10:02:37.060299264Z","1.08472","1.08481"
```

However, what I would really like is to further process this, using sed, to get

```
2020,05,05,10,02,37.060299264,1.08472,1.08481
```

and then append this to a file, let's call it "output," but when I try piping to sed I no longer see the streaming data although I'm sure my sed syntax is correct as I've checked it against a static test file.

So my question is: how do I further pipe to sed and then append to the file "output?"

Comment: Its probably just being buffered.

Comment: @muru How would I check if this is the case?

Comment: Use `stdbuf`, `unbuffer` or similar (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/70524) and see if you get output

Comment: @babelproofreader: `jq` itself has an option to unbuffer with `--unbuffered` flag

Comment: A combination of stdbuf, --unbuffered flag in jq and -u flag in sed accomplishes what I want. Thanks to muru and Inian.

Comment: @babelproofreader, please post an answer, otherwise this question has no value for future readers.

Comment: @glennjackman Done as requested.

Comment: @muru It does. In my posted answer I used the jq --unbuffered flag after it was suggested by Inian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to Glenn Jackman's comment requesting that I post an answer, the syntax that I find works for me is:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX..." "https://...=EUR_USD" | jq --raw-output --unbuffered '[.time, .bids[0].price, .asks[0].price] | @csv' | sed -u 's/["Z]//g' | sed -u 's/[-T:]/,/g' >> ~/path/to/append/to/output
```

which appends to the file in the desired format described in my original question. I can also look at the "output" file from time to time and see that the streaming data is continually being appended.