# View command output in scrollable pager

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, less

I would like to view the output of a command from the top and keep the terminal from jumping down, and I would like a terminal independent way for it. So without changing the terminal specific configuration. I tried using the `less` command like this:

```bsh
command | less
```

however on the commands I used, the pager exits after command output has finished.

How do I get the behavior where the command output is streamed into the pager in real-time, but I can view it top to bottom?

Comment: That is not the default behavior. Is your `less` aliased? Find it out with `type less`.

Comment: Appearently not: `less is /usr/bin/less`
The command with the described behavior is `cargo build | less`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not redirect stderr output to `less`, for some reason:

```bsh
command 2>&1 | less
```

yields the desired behavior.

by using `less -R` you can preserve colored output redirected from `command`, but some commands automatically omit coloring when their output is being redirected, and you need to look for an option like `--color=always` to always get colored output.

In my case, I now redirect my output to [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat), which is a clone of `cat`, with more features, with the options `--paging=always`, `--pager="less -RFX"` and `--number`, and I use `cargo build`s option `--color=always`:

```bsh
cargo build --color=always 2>&1 | bat --paging=always --pager="less -RFX" --number
```

Which yields nice, scrollable, colored output with numbered lines:

```rust
   1    Compiling openlimits v0.1.0 (/home/####/git/openlimits)
   2 error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `tokio`
   3   --> src/binance/client/websocket.rs:15:5
   4    |
   5 15 | use tokio::net::TcpStream;
   6    |     ^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `tokio`
   7
   8 error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `tokio_tungstenite`
   9   --> src/binance/client/websocket.rs:16:5
  10    |
  11 16 | use tokio_tungstenite::{
  12    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `tokio_tungstenite`
  13
  14 error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `tokio`
  15   --> src/coinbase/client/websocket.rs:10:5
  16    |
  17 10 | use tokio::net::TcpStream;
  18    |     ^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `tokio`
  19
....
```

Then I put the options in my configuration files for `bat` and `cargo`, to make them implicit, and now I get this behavior when typing

```bsh
cargo build 2>&1 | bat
```

In bash, appearently you can use `&>` instead of `2>&1`. [They are equivalent.](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-redirect-stderr-stdout/#:%7E:text=%3E%20%2Fdev%2Fnull-,Redirecting%20stderr%20to%20stdout,everything%20in%20a%20single%20file.&text=%3E%20file%20redirect%20the%20stdout%20to,order%20of%20redirection%20is%20important.)
In zsh, this does not seem to work, [although it is documented that way](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html).

Answer (score 7):

#### Not exiting at the end of the input

By default, less does not exit automatically, only if you use the quit command (`q`).

If you invoke `less` with the option `-E`, it exits when it reaches the end of the file. With the option `-e`, it exits when you try to move past the end of the file (for example by scrolling repeatedly). With the option `-F`, less exits immediately if the file is entirely displayed on one screen. None of these options are enabled by default, but there are a few ways they can be made the default on your system:

- `less` may be a shell alias with options. Check with `alias less`.
- Less reads options from the environment variable `LESS` when it starts. Check with `echo $LESS`.
- Less has a configuration file. Its default location is `.less` in your home directory; this can be changed by setting the environment variable `LESSKEY`. The file format is binary, but if options are set this way, both the string `LESS` and the options will appear in the file.
- It's unlikely, but if the environment variable `LESS_IS_MORE` is set, less behaves like the older utility `more`, including exiting on end of file by default.

#### Viewing command output before it's finished

When you pipe the input of a command into less (`mycommand | less`), less keeps reading until the command has finished. You can interrupt less with `Ctrl+C`, but then you won't be able to read any further output from the command, and the command may die due to a broken pipe. This is because less closes the pipe when it stops reading.

A workaround for this is to make the command output to a file and call less on that file. When less is reading from a file, you can type `F` and then `Ctrl+C` to make it read more data from the file then continue browsing.

```
mycommand >log 2>&1 &
less log
```

Programs may have a slightly different behavior depending on whether their output is a terminal, a pipe or a file. If you find that output is delayed when the output is a file or a pipe as opposed to a terminal, that's due to output [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer). See [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

The [`script` utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)) runs a program in a virtual terminal and logs the whole output to a file. As far as the program is concerned, it's writing output to a terminal. The program may use color escape sequences, for example. Pass the `-R` option to less to make it pass terminal escape sequences to the terminal rather than show control characters in escaped form.

```
script -c 'mycommand --option || echo "mycommand failed with status $?"' mycommand.log </dev/null >/dev/null &
less -R mycommand.log
```

Comment: Writing to a file is too much of an extra step, I am afraid, because I will have to delete the file afterwards. I would like a single command to do this.

Comment: @stimulate You can make a wrapper script that deletes the file afterwards. But you only need that if you want to scroll through the output before the command has finished, which apparently you don't.

Comment: Yes I want to, but I don't want to use any files for that. I shouldn't need to. A program can just manage its own buffer, which less already does.