# run command after every line of grep output appears

Tags: bash, grep, syslog, tail

I'm wanting to constantly monitor syslog and perform some computations after a regex pattern appears, and use the grep output in the command, as well as continue to monitor for new matching lines. The best way I can think to accomplish this is using `tail -f` and piping this output to `grep`. The only issue is I don't know of a way to run a new command based off each new line of output and continue until termination.

Any ideas on what I could use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is piping it to a while read. Quick example for just counting occurrences:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
tail -f input.txt | grep 'pattern' | while read line ; do
    a=$((a+1))
    echo -e "found match in $line , occurrence no. $a"
done
```

Tried with `dd if=/dev/random of=file` as reference. Assumption is that you only need 'pattern' as trigger and not the previous lines.

Comment: Note that you need to somehow make `grep` not buffer its output, otherwise the script will only see anything after some 4 kB or so is matched. With GNU grep, use `grep --line-buffered`, with other tools, perhaps something else. See. [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/170373).

Comment: Note that that would stip leading/trailing blanks from each line and interpret all escape sequences so, for example, `foo\tbar` in the input would become `foo<tab>bar` in the output. Always use `while IFS= read -r line` unless you have a specific **need** not to.