# Pipe from xwd to ImageMagick's convert produces cropped image

Tags: pipe, imagemagick, buffer

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a remote host (using `xwd`) and convert it to png (using `convert`). I need it to be an unattended oneliner, so this is what I'm doing:

```
sshpass -p THE_PASSWORD ssh user@192.168.1.1 xwd -display :0 -root | convert xwd:- output.png
```

The problem is that the generated PNG file is cropped, only the top part of the screen is shown. If I do the process in two steps, it works:

```
sshpass -p THE_PASSWORD ssh user@192.168.1.1 xwd -display :0 -root > output.xwd
convert output.xwd output.png
```

But I need it to be done in just one command.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the rate at which `convert` is receiving the data from the remote `xwd` command. I've tried using `stdbuf` [as mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/10105) to increase the buffer size, but does not seem to have any effect.

I'm using ImageMagick 6.7.8.9-15.

Answer (score 1):

> I need it to be done in just one command

If "one command" means a single shell expression, you could chain them with `&&`:

```bsh
sshpass -p THE_PASSWORD ssh user@192.168.1.1 xwd -display :0 -root > output.xwd && convert output.xwd output.png
```

Or if that doesn't work, you could use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```bsh
sshpass -p THE_PASSWORD ssh user@192.168.1.1 convert <(xwd -display :0 -root) output.png
```