# Tail a file and strip datetime

Tags: text-processing

I have a log file that contains the following content.

```
2021-06-15T22:50:11+00:00 DEBUG {"slug": "something", "key2": "value2"}
```

I would like to `tail -f` this file and pipe the results to `jq` command, but I need to strip out `2021-06-15T22:50:11+00:00 DEBUG` part before piping to `jq` since `jq` expects a JSON string.

Is there a way to tail the log file and strip the datetime part at the same time?

Ultimately, I would like to use the following command.

```bsh
tail -f :file | jq
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have access to GNU `sed` which is able to do unbuffered output:

```bsh
tail -f file | sed -u 's/^[^{]*//' | jq .
```

This would run `tail -f` on your file and continuously send new data to `sed`.  The `sed` command would strip everything up to the space before the first `{` on the line, and then send the result on to `jq`.

The `-u` option to GNU `sed` makes it not buffer the output.  Without this option, `sed` would buffer the result and would only send data to `jq` once the buffer (4 Kb?) was full.  Doing buffering like this is standard procedure when the output of a tool is not the terminal itself, and it's done for efficiency reasons.  In this case, we may want to turn the buffering off, so we use `-u`.

To  select only lines that contain the `DEBUG` string before the JSON data:

```bsh
tail -f file | sed -u -e '/^[^{]*DEBUG /!d' -e 's///' | jq .
```

or

```bsh
tail -f file | sed -u -n 's/^[^{]*DEBUG //p' | jq .
```

The `sed` command here would delete all lines that do not start with some text not containing `{` characters, ending in `DEBUG` .  If such a line is found, the matched text is removed, leaving the JSON data.

Note that we here extract the JSON based on the `DEBUG` string rather than the `{` that initiates a JSON object.

Related to buffering in pipelines:

- [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Answer (score 6):

To remove the first 2 space delimited columns:

```
tail -f file | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f3- | jq .
```

(`stdbuf -oL`, as found on GNU or FreeBSD systems, tricks `cut` into doing line-based instead of block-based output buffering).