# I don't understand `cat` behaviour when running `cat | ls`

Tags: pipe, cat

I know this is a useless command but I would like to understand why, wether in `bash` or `zsh`, when I enter `cat | ls`, `cat` will prompt me for input but only but will return after just one line whereas for example `</dev/stdin tr -d 'e' | ls` will let me input various line until I hit `Ctrl + D` ?

Comment: @zevzek You are right, the behavior is not different that `cat | ls`.
I think what I don't understand is what it means to own the `stdin`, I am not familiar with what that means which is why I did not understand the behavior. I have been answered below that it had to do with buffering but is there more to it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same reason why this only prints anything after 1 second:

```
(echo abc; sleep 1; echo def) | tr -d e |cat
```

With *stdout* redirected to a pipe, *most* utilities start to buffer the output and only write anything there after they have a full block of data. (With the size of the block being an implementation detail, it's probably some kilobytes.) There are some utilities you can use to disable the buffering, see: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/170373).

But some implementations of `cat` don't do buffering, and write immediately. That includes at least the GNU and Busybox implementations. What plain `cat` does with buffering is [not specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cat.html), there's only `cat -u` to *prevent* buffering.

Here, since `ls` doesn't read anything from *stdin* and hence the pipe, it probably finishes and exits faster than you can type anything. So, when `cat`/`tr` gets around to writing anything, the pipe is already closed, and the writer gets a SIGPIPE and exits. Since `cat` here writes what it reads immediately without buffering, it gets the signal immediately after the first input line. On the other hand, since `tr` waits to get a full buffer to write anything, the first input line doesn't trigger it. If you entered enough data, `tr` would also eventually write it to the pipe, get the signal and exit.

Like you said, piping to `ls` is silly, since it doesn't read anything. You could use something like `true` or `false` instead.

Comment: @ChrisDown 
Not sire I fully understans but could this explain why when I try make a program in C that forks, redirect stdout to a pipe, exec `cat`, forks again, exec `ls` then wait, `cat` behaves likes it is buffering ?

Comment: @ChrisDown, mm. The line buffering on input is the same for both `cat` and `tr` here. As far as I understand, it also has nothing to do with anything the process itself does for stdin, but with the _terminal_ being set to do line buffering (and editing) before the process sees anything. We could change that with `stty`, sure. Of course, that could be different on some other system I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @cassepipe, that sounds like a different question, and one what would require seeing the code.

Comment: @zevzek, while we're at it, I always had the impression that `setvbuf()` wouldn't do anything on an input stream, but is there something that explicitly says what should happen? Both [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) and the [POSIX text](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/setvbuf.html) only say vaguely that "many implementations only provide line buffering on input from terminal devices" and e.g. the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages-dev/setvbuf.3.en.html) on Debian  doesn't seem to say anything.

Comment: @zevzek, ah yes, of course. Of course that didn't affect the visible behaviour of my silly earlier test, e.g. `fgets()` still reads until it gets a full line, regardless of if it uses one `read()` or many. Thanks.

Comment: @zevzek It seems like you disagree with the answer I accepted. Would you mind crafting a more elaborate answer or pointing to documentation ?

Comment: @ilkkachu You asked to see some code so there is a naive version in C that does not behave the same (although cat is also connected to a pipe) : https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/50699b0b9ed74ceabb7718393ac7ad68

Comment: @cassepipe, it looks to me you have `cat` and `ls` in reverse there (i.e. you're doing `cat | ls`, not `ls | cat`). Also, the parent process has a copy of the write end of the pipe, so `cat` never sees EOF and never exits. Try e.g. what happens if you add the `-n` switch to `cat`. And then swap the programs around and `close(pipe_fd[WRITE_END]);` in the parent process before the `waitpid()` calls. Also you should check the return status of the `exec()` calls, or add a call to `_exit()` after them to make sure the children don't carry on running the rest of the code if the `exec()`s fail.

Comment: @cassepipe, on the other hand, if you did `cat | ls` on purpose, and expected `cat` to get a SIGPIPE and die, it doesn't because the parent also holds a copy of the _read end_ of the pipe, so SIGPIPE doesn't get sent. So, close that on the parent too.

Comment: @ilkkachu I was indeed trying to reproduce `cat | ls`. As you said I closed both pipe ends in the parent, and I do get the same behaviour. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`cat` without an argument will read from stdin, waiting until the first line is entered since [stdin is line buffered when referring to an interactive device](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html), and output it to its stdout, which is redirected to the stdin of `ls`. `ls` does not read from stdin at all, so it will simply output the list of files to stdout and exit. Since the `ls`-end of the pipe is closed by `ls` (`cat`'s stdout), `cat` will also exit.

The same behavior can be observed with any program which doesn't read from stdin and outputs to stdout. For example:

```
cat | uname -a
```

**Note:** `</dev/stdin` is superfluous. It will redirect stdin to stdin.